# What is the correct way to set Python's locale on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, localization, internationalization

I'm attempting to sort a list of strings in a locale-aware manner.  I've used the Babel library for other i18n-related tasks, but it doesn't support sorting.  Python's `locale` module provides a `strcoll` function, but requires the locale of the process to be set to the one I want to work with.  Kind of a pain, but I can live with it.

The problem is that I can't seem to actually set the locale.  The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) for the `locale` module gives this example:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')
```

When I run that, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\locale.py", line 494, in setlocale
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

It seems you're using Windows. The locale strings are different there. Take a more precise look at the doc:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE') # use German locale; name might vary with platform
```

On Windows, I think it would be something like:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')
```

MSDN has a list of [language strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/language-strings) and of [country/region strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/country-region-strings)

Comment: FWIW, I had the problem under `Ubuntu 13.04`, `Linux 3.8.0-19`, with python `2.7.4` when trying to set the locale to `fr_FR`. Setting it to `fr_FR.UTF-8` worked for me.

Comment: For Python 3.6.3 in Conda 4.4.11, Windows 7, the locale strings seem to be the same as other OS.

Comment: This list is more comprehensive: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc233982.aspx

Comment: The linked docs seem to be too recent for WServer2018R2 I had to do use `'eng_usa'` (`'en_US'` didn't work)

Answer (score 26):

You should **not pass an explicit locale** to setlocale, it is wrong. Let it find out from the environment. You have to pass it an empty string

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

Comment: I didn't mention this in the question because it wasn't directly related, but the code I was writing at the time was designed for use on a web server.  In other words, the locale might change with each request, and is not necessarily ever the same as the environment's locale.

Comment: DNS: Have you read the docs for locale? It implies it might be dangerous to call setlocale "much", and it is not thread safe. So perhaps something else than setlocale is the solution. Gettext can load different catalogs and switch at runtime for example; but I don't know what you are using the locale for.

Comment: Unless your user is not on your local machine

Answer (score 22):

This is the only correct way to set the German locale, as the OP is asking:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(
    category=locale.LC_ALL,
    locale="German"  # Note: do not use "de_DE" as it doesn't work
)
```

But please note, though, that it is best to set it like this:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(
    category=locale.LC_ALL,
    locale=""
)
```

We should pass an empty string to the `locale` argument as `locale=""`, which will automatically choose the default locale that is set on a user's operating system.

I strongly suggest that you always pass `locale=""`, because this is the only locale-independent way that will provide absolute versatility.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually answers the question.

Comment: this helped me, but I had to change `German` to `Portuguese_Brazil.1252`. Do you know a documentation listing these values?

Answer (score 10):

#### Ubuntu

On Ubuntu you may have this problem because you don't have that local installed on your system.

From shell try a:

```
$> locale -a
```

and check if you find the locale you are interested in. Otherwise you have to install it:

```
$> sudo apt-get install language-pack-XXX
```

where XXX is your language (in my case "xxx = it" , italian locale)
Then run a `dpkg-reconfigure`:

```
$> sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

After that try again in your python shell:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'it_IT.UTF-8')
```

(this is for italian locale, which was what I needed)

Comment: This question asks specifically about Windows

Answer (score 7):

I know this has been asked years ago, but I thought I'd try adding what I found out, using Python 3.6 on Windows:

```
import locale
for x in locale.windows_locale.values():
    print(x.replace('_','-'))
```

I tried some and that also seems to be a way of finding out, what's available on Windows.

Good to know: This for some reason is not compatible to strptime() at the current stable version of Python

And then you simply set the locale:

`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, any_item_of_the_printed_strings)`

Answer (score 5):

From locale.setlocale docs:

```
locale.setlocale(category, locale=None):
    """
    Set the locale for the given category.  The locale can be
    a string, an iterable of two strings (language code and encoding),
    or None.
    """"
```

Under Linux (especially Ubuntu) you can either use

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
```

or

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ('de', 'utf-8'))
```

You will get the same error if the locale is **not installed** on the system. So, make sure you have the locale **installed** on your system:

```
$ locale -a # to list the currently installed locales
$ (sudo) locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8 # to install new locale
```