# Locale date formatting in Python

Tags: python, date, locale

How do I get `datetime.datetime.now()` printed out in the native language?

```
>>> session.deathDate.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y")
'Fri, 12 Jun 2009'
```

I'd like to get the same result but in local language.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can just set the locale like in this example:

```
>>> import time
>>> print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
Sun, 23 Oct 2005 20:38:56
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "sv_SE") # swedish
'sv_SE'
>>> print time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
sön, 23 okt 2005 20:39:15
```

Comment: BTW it won't work under Windows. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale/956084#956084

Comment: It also requires the computer you run this on to have the locale you are trying to use generated. On GNU/Linux systems, locale -a will give you the listing of the available locales. The steps for adding new locales differ between distros.

Comment: Getting localized format of date/time by **changing locale is discouraged**. See my answer for the right solution.

Comment: this breaks in python3

Comment: In case the current system locale is already set to the desired locale, but still `strftime` is not honoring it, it may be due to the `datetime` module behavior. See this related [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue29457).

Comment: What is the scope of the `setlocale` call? Is the local restored after the function exits or is it permanently changed?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Test it? I use this at the top of my `main`, and it affects the rest of my program, all functions.

Comment: @Gauthier of course within the same program, but what about an unrelated program run in the same interpreter session?

Answer (score 119):

If your application is supposed to support more than one locale then getting localized format of date/time by changing locale (by means of `locale.setlocale()`) is discouraged. For explanation why it's a bad idea see Alex Martelli's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1551834/95735) to the the question [Using Python locale or equivalent in web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1551508/95735) (basically locale is global and affects whole application so changing it might change behavior of other parts of application)

You can do it cleanly using Babel package like this:

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, time
>>> from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time

>>> d = date(2007, 4, 1)
>>> format_date(d, locale='en')
u'Apr 1, 2007'
>>> format_date(d, locale='de_DE')
u'01.04.2007'
```

See [Date and Time](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/dates.html) section in Babel's documentation.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: How do I have to do this when applying to a column in a pandas dataframe? `df['day_of_week'] = format_date(df['date'], locale='de')` doesn't work

Comment: The author has commented on every other answer saying "_Getting localized format of date/time by changing locale is discouraged_", but failed to mention _why_ it is discouraged. Also, not everyone may be in a position to install a third-party package.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar My comment is _Getting localized format of date/time by changing locale is discouraged. *See my answer for the right solution.*_ You omitted the second sentence where I direct readers to my answer in which there is full explanation of why it's discouraged.

Answer (score 25):

You should use `%x` and `%X` to format the date string in the correct locale. E.g. in Swedish a date is represented as `2014-11-14` instead of `11/14/2014`.

The correct way to get the result as Unicode is:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, lang)
format_ = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%a, %x %X')
format_u = format_.decode(locale.getlocale()[1])
```

Here is the result from multiple languages:

```
Bulgarian пет, 14.11.2014 г. 11:21:10 ч.
Czech pá, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Danish fr, 14-11-2014 11:21:10
German Fr, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Greek Παρ, 14/11/2014 11:21:10 πμ
English Fri, 11/14/2014 11:21:10 AM
Spanish vie, 14/11/2014 11:21:10
Estonian R, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Finnish pe, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
French ven., 14/11/2014 11:21:10
Croatian pet, 14.11.2014. 11:21:10
Hungarian P, 2014.11.14. 11:21:10
Italian ven, 14/11/2014 11:21:10
Lithuanian Pn, 2014.11.14 11:21:10
Latvian pk, 2014.11.14. 11:21:10
Dutch vr, 14-11-2014 11:21:10
Norwegian fr, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Polish Pt, 2014-11-14 11:21:10
Portuguese sex, 14/11/2014 11:21:10
Romanian V, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Russian Пт, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Slovak pi, 14. 11. 2014 11:21:10
Slovenian pet, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Swedish fr, 2014-11-14 11:21:10
Turkish Cum, 14.11.2014 11:21:10
Chinese 周五, 2014/11/14 11:21:10
```

Comment: Great! but please mention that `.decode` is required only for Python 2

Comment: Getting localized format of date/time by **changing locale is discouraged**. See my answer for the right solution.

Answer (score 11):

Another option is:

```
>>> import locale
>>> import datetime
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME,'')
'es_CR.UTF-8'
>>> date_format = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)
>>> date_format
'%d/%m/%Y'
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> today
datetime.date(2012, 4, 23)
>>> today.strftime(date_format)
'23/04/2012'
```

Comment: `nl_langinfo` is not available on Windows (Python 2.7.8). See my answer for a platform compatible way.

Comment: Getting localized format of date/time by **changing locale is discouraged**. See my answer for the right solution.

Answer (score 9):

solution for russian language and cross platform

```
import sys
import locale
import datetime

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'rus_rus')
else:
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')

print(datetime.date.today().strftime("%B %Y"))
```

> Ноябрь 2017

Comment: have you got a solution for french language?

Comment: @mee i think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986/what-is-the-correct-way-to-set-pythons-locale-on-windows#comment27621025_956084) can help you

Comment: Getting localized format of date/time by **changing locale is discouraged**. See my answer for the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works in current Python 3.9 but also in Python 2.7.
There is no need to mess around with `local`. Just use the `strftime()` format strings `%c` (date and time), `%x` (date only) or `%X` (time only):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> now.strftime('%c')
'So 29 Mai 2022 17:06:17 '
>>> now.strftime('%x')
'29.05.2022'
>>> now.strftime('%X')
'17:06:17'
```

Comment: How would you control in which language the output is, though?

Comment: Your operating system does. The `local` package just "read" that settings from the operating system. You can overwrite the system settings as you can see on [@dEll's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47184351/4865723).

Comment: Ok so this is only a sufficient option if you don't need to change the locale programmatically (since locale setting seems to be discouraged).