# Using Python locale or equivalent in web applications?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

Python's locale implementation seems to want to either read the locale from system settings or have it be set via a setlocale call. Neither of these work for me since I'd like to use the capabilities in a web application, where the desired locale is the user's locale.

And there are warnings in the [locale docs](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html) that make the whole thing scary:

> On top of that, some implementation
>   are broken in such a way that frequent
>   locale changes may cause core dumps.
>   This makes the locale somewhat painful
>   to use correctly

And

> It is generally a bad idea to call
>   setlocale() in some library routine,
>   since as a side effect it affects the
>   entire program

So, is there a reasonable locale alternative for use in web apps? Is [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/0.9/index.html) it or are there other alternatives? I'm looking for something that will handle currencies as well as dates and numbers.

[Update] To clarify, I'm most interested in date, number, and currency formatting for various locales.

Answer (score 15):

`locale` is no good for any app that needs to support several locales -- it's really badly designed for those apps (basically any server-side app, including web apps).  Where feasible, [PyICU](https://gitlab.pyicu.org/main/pyicu) is a *vastly* superior solution -- top-quality i18n/L10n support, speed, flexibility (downside: while ICU's docs are good, PyICU's, well, not so much;-).  Alas, not always are you allowed to deploy your own extensions...:-(.

In particular, I'm still looking for a solid i18n/L10n solution for App Engine apps -- "translation" per se is the least of issues (you can just switch to the right set of templates), the problem is that there are many other L10n aspects (the ones that ICU supports so well, such as collation rules for example, etc, etc). I guess the already-mentioned [Babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) is the only sensible place to start from.

Comment: Is this still valid in 2019 with python >= 3.7?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use setlocale.**

Check how it is done in [django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/). It looks like they use class api of gettext library and do not use the setlocale function I bet there is a reason for this.

They manually store a [translation](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html#the-gnutranslations-class) per thread [check here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#yo88Sa0j8hQ/browser/django/branches/i18n/django/utils/translation.py?rev=726&format=txt&q=gettext&exact_package=http://code.djangoproject.net&l=123) how it is implemented (gettext function and _active dictionary).

Comment: this link has gone bad.

Answer (score 0):

Your best approach will be to `setlocale` on the locale that the browser passes you, if you're doing currencies, dates, and numbers.  There's a lot of zomgz warnings in the Python documentation for really off-color platforms; most of these can be ignored.

"Frequent locale changes" shouldn't matter, unless I'm missing something.

You're not doing message catalogs or anything fancy, so stick with what Python gives you.

Comment: setlocale isn't thread safe. On any multi-threaded web server setting the locale for one request will interfere with the locale for another, with bizarre results.

Answer (score 0):

Django's i18n framework works out the shortcomings of `setlocale()` by not using it. This way the locale is set per request and if you use `LocaleMiddleware` it can be set to change according to UserAgent `Accept-Language` setting. See the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/#id2).

Comment: Thanks zgoda. I'm looking for some of the features provided by locale - in particular, currency, name, and number formatting. I didn't see those in the django docs.

Comment: These belong to l10n (localization), not i18n. I can recommend Babel - http://babel.edgewall.org/, it has nice Django integration and is much more accurate than python's built in locale module.