# Strange behaviour while replacing string in python

Tags: python, replace

I have a date given in format "October 28, 2010" (or simillar). Now I want to change the full name of month to shorter version (in this case Oct). For this I prepared a dictionary:

```
_mapping = {'January': 'Jan', 
            'February': 'Feb', 
            'March': 'Mar', 
            'April': 'Apr', 
            'May': 'May', 
            'June': 'Jun', 
            'July': 'Jul', 
            'August': 'Aug', 
            'September': 'Sep', 
            'October': 'Oct', 
            'November': 'Nov', 
            'December': 'Dec'}
```

and in the method where the substition goes I wrote following:

```
def fetch(self, pno):
    ...
    date = #get data (working fine)
    for l, s in self._mapping.iteritems():
        pubdate = date.replace(l, s)
        print l + " -> " + pubdate #this is only for debug
    (pubd_month, self.pubd_day, self.pubd_year) = pubdate.split(' ')
    print pubd_month, self.pubd_day, self.pubd_year
    print pubdate
```

The result of execution is:

```
February -> October 28, 2008
October -> Oct 28, 2008
January -> October 28, 2008
April -> October 28, 2008
November -> October 28, 2008
March -> October 28, 2008
August -> October 28, 2008
May -> October 28, 2008
December -> October 28, 2008
June -> October 28, 2008
September -> October 28, 2008
July -> October 28, 2008
October
October 28, 2008
```

As you can see it seems that the replacement goes ok when it finds October but outside the loop I get again full month name. What do I do wrong?

Another question: is there shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for `_mapping`. If you use [datetime.datetime](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) objects, the `strftime` method can return the abbreviated month for you:

```
import datetime as DT

def short_date(date):
    date = DT.datetime.strptime(date, '%B %d, %Y')
    return date.strftime('%b %d, %Y')

print(short_date('October 28, 2010'))
```

prints

```
Oct 28, 2010
```

If your date strings come in a variety of formats then instead of parsing them with `strptime(date, '%B %d, %Y')` you could use dateutil's [parser.parse](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-c0e81a473b647dfa787dc11e8c69557ec2c3ecd2) method. For greatest flexibility, you'll probably be best served parsing the date strings into `datetime.datetime` objects as early as possible, and using `strftime` to format them as late as possible.

Comment: Note that the `%b` and `%B` month names are locale dependent. I've found that if your code has to run on different environments where you  do not control the locale, you have to do manual month replacements *anyway*.

Comment: Is it possible to force using english locale then?

Comment: Not really; it is far easier to just replace the strings, to be honest. See [Locale date formatting in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/985505) for a solution that *may* work on POSIX systems, provided the locale has been generated.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are *always* replacing `pubdate` with a replacement on `date`, you overwrite any successful matching.

Either *test* first if the month is in the string *before* replacing, or replace `pubdate` with `pubdate.replace()` results:

```
pubdate = #get data (working fine)
for l, s in self._mapping.iteritems():
    pubdate = pubdate.replace(l, s)
```

or, using testing:

```
date = #get data (working fine)
for l, s in self._mapping.iteritems():
    if l in date:
        pubdate = date.replace(l, s)
```

The latter still will result in `pubdate` being overwritten if more than one month name is found. Alternatively, if there is only ever going to be *one* month match, use `break` to end the loop early:

```
date = #get data (working fine)
for l, s in self._mapping.iteritems():
    if l in date:
        pubdate = date.replace(l, s)
        break
```

Caveat: if *no* match is ever found, `pubdate` will never have been assigned to and you'll get a `UnboundLocal` exception.

Comment: Huh, silly mistake of mine. Thanks :) However though in this specific situation ubutbu's solution is cleaner so I'll mark his as accepted.