# Pandas locale settings for to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas

Where is pandas picking up the locale settings for date conversion?

It seems that the to_datetime function is producing different results compare to java's jodatime. In particular, determining week of the year, and week year seem to produce different results between US and GB local in java.

thanks,

Comment: Hi there UCL buddy :)

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python#985517