# How to add specific "controls" to a function? (edit:added full function)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
function(['28-02-2016','31-02-2016'])
['february', '*']
```

EDIT (full function)

```
import calendar
def function(monthList):
    months = {"01": "january", "02":"february", "03":"march", "04":"april", "05":"may", "06":"june", "07":"july", "08":"august", "09":"september", "10":"october", "11":"november", "12":"december"}
    returnList = []
    for monthStr in monthList:
            month = str(monthStr)[3:5]
    if month in months.keys():
        if int(monthStr[:2]) <= calendar.monthrange(int(monthStr[-4:]), int(monthStr[3:5]))[1]:
            returnList.append(months[month])
        else:
            returnList.append("*")
    else:
        returnList.append("*")
return returnList
```

If the date is right, the function creates a list where the month is put, otherwise a `'*'` is put. But if I write:

```
function([02-02-20a1]:
```

I get this error:

```
     6         month = str(monthStr)[3:5]
     7         if month in months.keys():
---> 8             if int(monthStr[:2]) <= calendar.monthrange(int(monthStr[-4:]), int(monthStr[3:5]))[1]:
     9                 returnList.append(months[month])
    10             else:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '20a1'
```

So Python is telling me I have to put a control in the list number 8. How do I manage to tell the function to act like this?

```
function(['02-02-19a1'])
[*]
```

Comment: It's telling you that `'20a1'` isn't a valid integer literal. If you get a `ValueError` you can assume it's not a valid date, so see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html for error handling. Also, you can simplify significantly with `datetime`'s built-in parsing, which will deal correctly with e.g. leap years.

Comment: Python tells that you have error in your code / input

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "controls". Clearly though "20a1" and "19a1" are not valid values to pass to `int`.

Comment: *"Python is telling me I have to put a control in the list number 8"* - No. Where did you get that idea from? It is just telling you that `'20a1'` is not an integer. You should catch that exception and return `'*'`. I can't really give you a more specific answer because you did not show the whole function.

Comment: @DanielRoseman int(*, base=10) you wanted to say

Comment: I am pretty sure there are better ways then what you use in the function, but since we cannot see the full function, the general idea is that a try/except should do the job.

Comment: Your code assumes that the `str(monthStr)` string is composed entirely of digits and hyphens in certain positions. Which is obviously not true for `'02-02-19a1'`. You need to check the format in advance (and not try to parse it if it's wrong) _or_ add `try/except` around statements that can fail and handle the cases where the assumption was wrong.

Comment: i added the text of the function further clarification guys,  meanwhile thanks you guys for have been helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Python `time.strptime` and `time.strftime`:

```
import time

def get_month(date_string):
    try:
        t = time.strptime(date_string,'%d-%m-%Y')
        return time.strftime('%B', t).lower()
    except ValueError:
        return '*'
```

If the date is invalid, `ValueError` will be raised, in which case you return `'*'`.

Call `get_month` for each date string in your function.

```
def get_months(date_strings):
    return [get_month(date_string) for date_string in date_strings]
```

Comment: That would not cover e.g. `function(['bla-7-99', 'iiiiiiiiiii'])`

Comment: Edited to use `strftime` and `strptime` instead.

Comment: so i just have to add this little paragraph to the test of my function?

Comment: @xli what if i wanted to add a list of potential dates as an input?

Comment: You can add this function to your module. In your other function, call `get_month` for each potential date in the list, and add each result to a list, which you then return. More concisely, `return [get_month(monthStr) for monthStr in monthList]`

Comment: get_month(['02-02-10a1','02-02-1992'])

Comment: strptime() argument 0 must be str, not <class 'list'>   the function still doesn't allow me to put a list as an input

Comment: I mean add a function `get_months` with definition `return [get_month(monthStr) for monthStr in monthList]`

Comment: it works perfectly , thanks :)                                                                           curiosity: is it possible to return februar (february into german) instead of february?

Comment: @Vibes You can set the locale as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/985517/1231717). If the answer worked for you, you can accept it by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer.