# Python month/day names in other language

Tags: python, python-2.7, local

Debian is set to `en_US` but I need day/month in **German**.

So how can I get `%a` to output `Do` instead of `Thu`?

```
draw.text((0,34), time.strftime("%a %d.%m.%Y"), font=font)
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Linux**

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8')
'de_DE.UTF-8'
>>> d = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> d.strftime("%a %d.%m.%Y")
'Do 24.05.2018'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code below and then just continue to use strftime:

```
import locale
# for German locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "de_DE")
```

If you use windows, syntax change to:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'deu_deu')
```