# write custom string formatter

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, formatter

I’m writing a datetime package for my culture and i need string formating feature like strptime, strftime in datetime package.

i wrote code below and it’s work perfectly. but it didn’t make me feel good.

i don’t like to use [format](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format).

Thanks for sharing with me if there is another way.

```
_replaces = {
    "%y": "{year:y}",
    "%m": "{month:m}",
    "%n": "{month_name:n}",
    "%d": "{day:d}",
    "%h": "{hour:h}",
    "%M": "{minute:M}",
    "%s": "{second:s}",
}

_month_names = [
    ...
]

class _TimeFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, spec):
        value = cgi.escape(value)
        spec = spec[:-1] + 's'
        return super(_TimeFormatter, self).format_field(value, spec)


def _do_replace(format):
    for k, v in _replaces.items():
        format = format.replace(k, v)
    return format


def fmt(date_time, format="%y/%m/%d %h:%M:%s"):
    format = _do_replace(format)
    jd = ...
    date = ...
    date_dict = {
        "year": date[0],
        "month": date[1],
        "month_name": _month_names[int(date[1])],
        "day": date[2],
        "hour": str(date_time.hour),
        "minute": str(date_time.minute),
        "second": str(date_time.second),
    }
    return _TimeFormatter().format(format, **date_dict)

# example = fmt(
#   datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 28, 1, 10, 33),
#   "%h:%M:%s %d/%m/%y"
#)
# output: "1:10:33 7/3/1398"
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use `format`?

Comment: it's more easier and most of users have experience with `strptime` and `strftime`,

Comment: Check this out: https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/  It's my new favorite part of Python

Comment: You don't like `strftime`, so you implemented your own which uses `format`, but you don't like `format` either? What do you like? :P

Comment: @zvone actuly i like `strftime` but it implemented for english date time not my culture

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python ?