# Translate a date in the python source in django

Tags: python, django, internationalization, translation

How can I translate a date in my `views.py`? If I try to translate it with `gettext` it returns me this error: `an integer is required (got type str)`.
For translating a date i mean for example from english version (May 30, 2019) to italian one (30 Maggio 2019). I've to return the date in a json response. This is my code:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
...
@AutoLanguage #It's a middleware that enables i18n
date = datetime.date.today()
date_translated = _(date)
return JsonResponse({'date': date_translated})
```

Comment: Django can not translate a `date` object. You can set the `locale`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/985517/67579

Answer (score 2):

Use [`locale.setlocale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.setlocale) in your view:

```
import locale

def view_name(request):

   QUERY_RESULT = MODEL_NAME.objects.get(pk=event_id) #ANY QUERY

    try:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'fr_FR.utf8') #your language encoding
    except:
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'fr_FR')

    translated_date = QUERY_RESULT.DATE.strftime("%A %d %B %Y") #<= format you want
```

You'll find the strftime formats in [the datetime doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html)

for me it gives `translated_date = "mardi 11 juin 2019"`

Comment: Note that this will have an effect even after the view finishes executing, presumably.

Comment: If you're using a recent python version, this will throw an error on production. I'm actually here to find another way to do this.