# Parse datetime string not in english

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, localization

I can't parse a date written in italian:

```
 datetime.strptime("sab 21 mar 2020, 13:04", "%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M")
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: time data 'sab 21 mar 2020, 13:04' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M'
```

If I try with:

```
datetime.strptime("sat 21 mar 2020, 13:04", "%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M")
```

It's ok, so how can parse the date in the right local time?
In Java, I did so:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm", Locale.ITALIAN);
```

with this line I was able to parse date correcly, does exist something similar in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locale date formatting in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the linked question because this is about _parsing_ not about _formatting_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the locale to the appropriate region.

```py
import datetime
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "italian")
print(datetime.datetime.strptime("sab 21 mar 2020, 13:04", "%a %d %b %Y, %H:%M"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2020-03-21 13:04:00
```