# Conversion of date formats

Tags: python, datetime, datetime-conversion

I wanted to convert a list containing dates in the format:

```
01 MAR 2020
```

Into this format :

```
2020-03-01 (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

using python.
Is there a way to do this??

Comment: What is the "main issue" about MAR being capitalized? What happened when you tried `"%d %b %Y"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes using `datetime`

```py
from datetime import datetime

# Python object
datetime.strptime("01 MAR 2020", "%d %b %Y")
# datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0)

# Converted Format
datetime.strptime("01 MAR 2020", "%d %b %Y").strftime('%F')
# 2020-03-01'
```

---

**PS** The locale used might cause problems when dealing with non-numeric months. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python) for help on the topic.

Comment: I get a "ValueError: time data '01 MAR 2020' does not match format '&d %b %Y'" from your first code excerpt.

Comment: @Cribber That might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python

Comment: ah, the code worked when I set locale to us_US. Good to know!