# Python Datetime in greek language

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

I want to convert this type of time: `Μαρτίου 23 2021 19:20`  Μαρτίου = month
to datetime.

I used this format but didnt match:
`df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format = '%B %d %Y %H:%M')`

How could I solve it? Should I set the greek datetime in a way? How ??

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python.

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan the answer that you have linked won't work. Read the comments.

Comment: @Maze Issue was closed citing the link I shared above. It won't have the entire solution that can be simply copy-pasted from, but a hint on how to go about doing it.

Comment: In addition, what you link is actually converts current time (which already in date format) to a different language, which isn't what the OP is having :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use another library to translate Greek to English then you will convert the date from string to date type, here is a testable example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from google_trans_new import google_translator

# set translator
translator = google_translator()

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        "Time": [
            "Ιανουάριος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Φεβρουάριος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Μάρτιος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Απρίλιος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Μάιος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Ιούνιος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Ιούλιος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Αύγουστος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Σεπτέμβριος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Οκτώβριος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Νοέμβριος 23 2021 19:20",
            "Δεκέμβριος 23 2021 19:20",
        ]
    }
)

def convert(given_date):
    data = given_date.split(" ")
    # convery from Greek to English
    data[0] = translator.translate(data[0], lang_tgt="en")
    return " ".join(data)

# convert from Greek to English using mapping in Pandas
df["Time"] = df["Time"].apply(convert)
# convert time from string to date
df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format="%B %d %Y %H:%M")

# display results
print(df["Time"].iloc[:])
```

### Clarification

After looking into it, it seems that `googletrans` library has some issues, so I am using `google_trans_new` to do the translation part. [1]

[1] [googletrans stopped working with error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455774/googletrans-stopped-working-with-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-group)