# Add local day of the week column based on date column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a pandas dataframe that contains a `date` column. I would like to add another column called `day_of_week` to this df that tells the day of the week in German. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985505/locale-date-formatting-in-python), I understand that I can do this by using the [Babel package](https://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/dates.html).

```
>>> from datetime import date, datetime, time
>>> from babel.dates import format_date, format_datetime, format_time

>>> d = date(2007, 4, 1)
>>> format_date(d, locale='en')
u'Apr 1, 2007'
>>> format_date(d, locale='de_DE')
u'01.04.2007'
```

However, when I try to apply this to a pandas dataframe column, I get an `AssertionError:`:

`df['day_of_week'] = format_date(df['date'], "E", locale='de_DE')`

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Are you on linux or windows?

Comment: Linux. However, I prefer to use the Babel package due to the reasons given in the answer mentioned above

Comment: this works fine for me: `format_date(d, "E", locale='de_DE')` --> 'So.'

Comment: @Paul, yes but not with a dataframe as argument. You need to  `apply`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `apply`:

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['date'].apply(format_date, format='E', locale='de_DE')
print(df)

# Output
        date day_of_week
0 2022-01-28         Fr.
1 2022-01-29         Sa.
2 2022-01-30         So.
3 2022-01-31         Mo.
4 2022-02-01         Di.
5 2022-02-02         Mi.
6 2022-02-03         Do.
7 2022-02-04         Fr.
8 2022-02-05         Sa.
9 2022-02-06         So.
```

Setup:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2022-1-28', '2022-2-6')})
print(df)

# Output
        date day_of_week
0 2022-01-28         Fr.
1 2022-01-29         Sa.
2 2022-01-30         So.
3 2022-01-31         Mo.
4 2022-02-01         Di.
5 2022-02-02         Mi.
6 2022-02-03         Do.
7 2022-02-04         Fr.
8 2022-02-05         Sa.
9 2022-02-06         So.
```

As a suggestion with `locales`:

```
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'de_DE.UTF-8')  # Linux
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'German')  # Windows

df['day_of_week'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%a.')
```