# How to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?

Tags: python

I have a string that represents a number which uses commas to separate thousands.  How can I convert this to a number in python?

```
>>> int("1,000,000")
```

Generates a `ValueError`.

I could replace the commas with empty strings before I try to convert it, but that feels wrong somehow.  Is there a better way?

---

<sub>For `float` values, see [How can I convert a string with dot and comma into a float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/), although the techniques are essentially the same.</sub>

Comment: No, that's the most pythonic solution.  ```int("1,000,000".replace(',', ''))```

Answer (score 128, accepted):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' ) 
locale.atoi('1,000,000')
# 1000000
locale.atof('1,000,000.53')
# 1000000.53
```

Comment: I think the guru means something like this:

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

Comment: Very nice. This way I can handle european numbers where the commas and points are switched too.  Thanks.

Comment: I get locale error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\test\locale_num.py", line 2, in <module>
    locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )
  File "F:\Python27\lib\locale.py", line 539, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting`

Comment: @TonyVeijalainen: On linux you can use `locale -a` to find what locales are available on your system. For Windows, try this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/956084/190597).

Comment: Where did you find out that it was `'en_US.UTF-8'`? (It's correct - I just want to know for future reference.) It doesn't show up in a Google search of the python.org website, nor is there any list on the locale doc page: https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html EDIT: I see that you can find the locales with `locale -a`... so the interpreter gets the information about locales from the OS itself?

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius: On Linux the locales are [provided by glibc](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Locales).

Comment: Is there any way, similar to this answer, to convert a string with commas to a decimal?

Comment: @EliasZamaria: I don't think there is a builtin function, but you could use replace to remove the commas: `decimal.Decimal('123,456.789'.replace(',',''))`.

Comment: @unutbu, thanks. I know I can do that. I was just wondering if there was a simpler way, similar to your answer.

Comment: This did not work for me, but this did - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843193/convert-a-number-using-atof/48845430#48845430

Answer (score 50):

There are several ways to parse numbers with thousands separators. And I doubt that the way described by @unutbu is the best in all cases. That's why I list other ways too.

1. The proper place to call `setlocale()` is in `__main__` module. It's global setting and will affect the whole program and even C extensions (although note that LC_NUMERIC setting is not set at system level, but is emulated by Python). Read [caveats in documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/locale.html#background-details-hints-tips-and-caveats) and think twice before going this way. It's probably OK in single application, but never use it in libraries for wide audience. Probably you shoud avoid requesting locale with some particular charset encoding, since it might not be available on some systems.
2. Use one of third party libraries for internationalization. For example [PyICU](http://pyicu.osafoundation.org/) allows using any available locale wihtout affecting the whole process (and even parsing numbers with particular thousands separators without using locales):

   NumberFormat.createInstance(Locale('en_US')).parse("1,000,000").getLong()
3. Write your own parsing function, if you don't what to install third party libraries to do it "right way". It can be as simple as `int(data.replace(',', ''))` when strict validation is not needed.

Comment: +1 for recommending the simple way.  That's all I needed when I had this same problem.

Comment: Edited to fix a typo (`setlocate` should be `setlocale`).  Also, +1.

Comment: Shameless self-promotion, I did use the third option. So if someone is interested, have a look at [**this question/answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48843193/convert-a-number-using-atof/48845430#48845430)

Answer (score 21):

Replace the commas with empty strings, and turn the resulting string into an `int` or a `float`.

```
>>> a = '1,000,000'
>>> int(a.replace(',' , ''))
1000000
>>> float(a.replace(',' , ''))
1000000.0
```

Comment: Please, read again the OP question. In particular where he says: "I could replace the commas with empty strings before I try to convert it, but that feels wrong somehow. Is there a better way?"

Answer (score 3):

I got locale error from accepted answer, but the following change works here in Finland (Windows XP):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'english_USA' )
print locale.atoi('1,000,000')
# 1000000
print locale.atof('1,000,000.53')
# 1000000.53
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

(A dirty but quick way)

```
>>> a='-1,234,567,89.0123'
>>> "".join(a.split(","))
'-123456789.0123'
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this. It goes a bit beyond the question:
You get an input. It will be converted to string first (if it is a list, for example from Beautiful soup);
then to int,
then to float.

It goes as far as it can get. In worst case, it returns everything unconverted as string.

```
def to_normal(soupCell):
    ''' converts a html cell from beautiful soup to text, then to int, then to float: as far as it gets.
    US thousands separators are taken into account.
    needs import locale'''
    
    locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'english_USA' ) 

    output = unicode(soupCell.findAll(text=True)[0].string)
    try: 
        return locale.atoi(output)
    except ValueError: 
        try: return locale.atof(output)
        except ValueError:
            return output
```

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic solution would be int("1,000,000".replace(',', ''))

But if you will not want to use .replace() and lets say also not want to import anything.

```
string = '1,000,000,000'
# string_w_float = '1,000,000,000.5'

no_comma = ''
for num in string:
    # if num == '.':
    #   break       # own code here for after decimal
    try:
        no_comma += str(int(num))
    except:
        pass
print(int(no_comma))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> print locale.atoi('1,000,000')
1000000
>>> print locale.atof('1,000,000.53')
1000000.53
```

this is done on Linux in US.

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but the babel library has *parse_decimal* and *parse_number* which do exactly what you want:

```
from babel.numbers import parse_decimal, parse_number
parse_decimal('10,3453', locale='es_ES')
>>> Decimal('10.3453')
parse_number('20.457', locale='es_ES')
>>> 20457
parse_decimal('10,3453', locale='es_MX')
>>> Decimal('103453')
```

You can also pass a Locale class instead of a string:

```
from babel import Locale
parse_decimal('10,3453', locale=Locale('es_MX'))
>>> Decimal('103453')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `pandas` and you're trying to parse a CSV that includes numbers with a comma for thousands separators, you can just pass the keyword argument `thousands=','` like so:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('your_file.csv', thousands=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest solution, but for the sake of completeness and maybe interesting if you want to rely on an existing function that has been proven a million times: you can leverage [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) by injecting your number as StringIO to its `read_csv()` function (it has a C backend, so the conversion functionality cannot be leveraged directly - as far as I know).

```
>>> float(pd.read_csv(StringIO("1,000.23"), sep=";", thousands=",", header=None)[0])
1000.23
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
def changenum(data):
    foo = ""
    for i in list(data):
        if i == ",":
            continue
        else:
            foo += i
    return  float(int(foo))
```

Comment: Some explanation to go with that code? A bowl of soup is usually served with a soup spoon