# Python parse comma-separated number into int

Tags: python, string-conversion

How would I parse the string `1,000,000` (one million) into it's integer value in Python?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-tho/1779324

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
>>> a = '1,000,000'
>>> int(a.replace(',', ''))
1000000
>>>
```

Answer (score 61):

There's also a simple way to do this that should handle internationalization issues as well:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> locale.atoi("1,000,000")
1000000
>>>
```

I found that I have to explicitly set the locale first as above, otherwise it doesn't work for me and I end up with an ugly traceback instead:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 296, in atoi
    return atof(str, int)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 292, in atof
    return func(string)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,000,000'
```

Comment: Do you mean:

`locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')`

I.e. "UTF-8", not "UTF8". On my OSX machine that seems to be the correct value.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The comma-replacement hack is brittle and i18n-breaking.

Comment: This still converts wrong values like 1,0,0,10 to 10010

Comment: @Seperman Under the hood, `locale.atoi` and friends  just do `val.replace(sep, '')`, where `sep` is the thousands separator defined in the locale convention.

Comment: Exactly. I don't think that is the right approach.

Answer (score 14):

Replace the ',' with '' and then cast the whole thing to an integer.

```
>>> int('1,000,000'.replace(',',''))
1000000
```