# i am trying to get a value from a .csv file in python and facing this error

Tags: python, csv, input

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '405,000'`

the code is as follows :

```
for d in csv.DictReader(open(c_name + '.csv'), delimiter=','):
    global d_value
    d_value = int(d['Debt Value'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a comma in your value, which is why you're seeing the error. You may want to sanitize your numbers by doing something like this:

```
    d_value = int(d['Debt Value'].replace(",", ""))
```

While you're at it, it's a good idea to close your files when you're done with them. You can use a [with statement](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example) to make sure it will close after your block.

```
with open(c_name + ".csv") as csvfile:
    for d in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        global d_value
        d_value = int(d['Debt Value'].replace(",", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

`405,000` isn't a valid `int`. You either need to remove that comma:

```
d_value = int(d['Debt Value'].replace(',', ''))
```

Or [use the `locale` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954231/464744):

```
import locale

# You might need to set a locale
# locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

d_value = locale.atoi(d['Debt Value'])
```