# Sorting a CSV file based on a string column as integer comparison

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I want to sort my CSV file with the first column. The first column has strings in it but the values are numbers. So I want to sort it as an integer. I know I can sort using the following -

```
sortedList = sorted(mycsv, key=lambda t: float(t[0]))
```

But this gives the following error -

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 14,481.72
```

I read a couple of SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953746/python-parse-comma-separated-number-into-int) and found out that the solution to get rid of that error is by doing this -

```
float(value.replace(',',''))
```

However I do not know how to do this while sorting using lambda function. I somehow cannot put this logic into the first line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace in the `lambda`, you want to sort by `t[0]` the first element so you need to convert that element to a `float` in your `lambda`:

```
float(t[0].replace(",",""))

sorted(mycsv, key=lambda t: float(t[0].replace(",","")))

In [12]: l = ["5,543.23","14,481.72","10,1000.34","8,581.72"]

In [13]:  sorted(l, key=lambda t: float(t.replace(",","")))
Out[13]: ['5,543.23', '8,581.72', '14,481.72', '10,1000.34']
```