# Convert number string to number using python 3.6+

Tags: python-3.x

I have got the value from database 350,000,000.00 now I need to convert it to 350000000. 
Please provide a solution on this using Python 3.6+ version

Thanks

Comment: the comma's are included?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python parse comma-separated number into int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953746/python-parse-comma-separated-number-into-int)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use Python to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th)

Comment: This is not duplicate. I am getting number with comma separated, then I need to add "", then remove comma and dot(.).

Answer (score 4):

Let the input be in a variable, say

```
a="350,000,000.00"
```

Since, the digits are comma `,` separated, that needs to be removed.

```
a.replace(",","")
>>> 350000000.00
```

The resultant `string` is a `float`. When we directly convert the string to integer, it will result in an error.

```
int(a.replace(",",""))
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '350000000.00'
```

So, convert the number to `float` and then to `int`.

```
int(float(a.replace(",","")))
>>>350000000
```

Comment: Please note that I am getting 350,000,000.00 not "350,000,000.00" . How I will convert 350,000,000.00 to "350,000,000.00" . please let me know

Comment: @Kuladip Just read, it is sourced from DB. The values will be string by default. Try using the string function on the field.

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in a variable and then parse it with int(variable_name)

eg. If you store the value in variable a, just write
    int(float(a))

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert(a):
    r = 0
    s = a.split(".")[0]
    for c in s.split(","):
        r = r * 1000 + int(c)
    return r

s = convert("350,000,000.00")
```

Comment: Please note that I am getting 350,000,000.00 not "350,000,000.00" . How I will convert 350,000,000.00 to "350,000,000.00" . please let me know