# how to convert single quotes string to number in python

Tags: python, string, int, single-quotes

I have a number of type string with single quotes. e,g

```
var = '2,000'
type(var) # <class 'str'>
```

I want to convert it to int.

I have tried `int(var)` But it gives an error

> invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,000'

Comment: You have a `,` in your string, you need to remove it before you can convert

Comment: Take a look at this question :) : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953746/python-parse-comma-separated-number-into-int

Comment: BTW, you actually lied in the question, when you wrote `var = '2000'`, because that string does not produce an error. The error happens when the string is `var = '2,000'`, so you should put that in the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I was an idiot!! completely overlooked it. Yes it was supposed to be '2,000' NOT '2000' and I've updated in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your number contains ',' then you should use this.

```
 > var = '2,000'
 > int(a.replace(',', ''))
 > 2000
```

else this

```
 >  var = '2000'
 >  i = int(var)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var = '2000'

print(type(int(var)))
```

Output:

`<class 'int'>`

Explanation:

Use the `int` to convert into `integer`

Comment: No, don't use `eval()`. There are easier, safer ways of converting it.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Thanks. I have updated it

Answer (score 2):

I get these results :

```
var = '2000'
print(type(var)) # <class 'str'>
myInt = int(var)
print(type(myInt)) # <class 'int'>
```

So could you try and share all your relevant code please.

Answer (score 2):

I think your error message shows you are using "2,000" not "2000"
try using str.replace to remove comas or any letters in your strings

```
 int ("2,000,000".replace("," , ""))
```