# How to skip comma and space, but not changing the value

Tags: python, list

I just start learning python, and would like to ask the reader to input a number,but i would like to skip comma and space that reader input.

```
a = input("input a number:")
x = y
print(dec(x))
```

However, if i use split, it would become a list or 2 number
for example, when user input `12,3456`, 
and `y` would become `['12', '3456']`

And my expected output is `123456` as a integer but not a list with two values.

I tried to use `replace` before, but it said

> "TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()"

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: You could use *str.replace* to get rid of each of the unwanted characters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python parse comma-separated number into int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953746/python-parse-comma-separated-number-into-int)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using split, you can just use replace to remove any comma or space from the string you read from input.

```
a=input("input a number:")
a = a.replace(",","").replace(" ","")
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this.

```
>>> number = int("".join(input().split(',')))
12,3456
>>> number
123456
>>>
```

Basically just splitting the input based on `','` and then joining them

You could also try replacing the `','` with `''`

```
>>> number = int(input().replace(',',''))
12,3456
>>> number
123456
>>>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried and it said that TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len(), how can i solve it?