# receiving "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '989,415"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics, data-manipulation

I keep coming across the same issue no matter how many solutions I come up with. I downloaded population data from the united census bureau, and using pandas, I created a data frame. I wanted to do a **summary of statistics across all the states** and create a **line chart for one of the states**( it can be any state). the problem is, I keep getting "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '989,415'".

link for the data:
https://data.census.gov/cedsci/table?q=population%20by%20state&tid=PEPPOP2019.PEPANNRES

This is what I have so far.( The lines with the # are all the solutions I've tried)

````
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#open file
with open('/Users/Documents/population data.csv', 'r') as data_file:
      
     #create a dataframe and read the file into it 
     df= pd.read_csv(data_file)

     #rename/clean up headers
     df= df.set_axis(['state', '4/1/2010 census popolation', 
                  '4/1/2010', 
                  '7/1/2010', 
                  '7/1/2011',
                  '7/1/2012',
                  '7/1/2013',
                  '7/1/2014', 
                  '7/1/2015', 
                  '7/1/2016', 
                  '7/1/2017', 
                  '7/1/2018',
                  '7/1/2019'],  axis= 'columns')
     
     #indexed by 'state'
     df.set_index('state', inplace= True)
     
     #change values to integer
     df.dtypes
     
     df.describe()
     
     #df["4/1/2010 census popolation"] = df["4/1/2010 census popolation"].astype("int")
    
    
     #df.astype({"4/1/2010 census popolation":'int', "4/1/2010":'int'}) 
     
     #df['4/1/2010 census popolation']= df['4/1/2010 census popolation'].apply(np.int64)
  
     
     #pd.to_numeric(df)```

[screenshot of the data frame][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRkl9.jpg
````

Answer (score 0):

[Your issue is trying to convert a string with commas to ints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953746/python-parse-comma-separated-number-into-int). Try iterating through string replacements before doing integer conversions.