# How to remove the commas from string with no spaces for int conversion

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, integer

[image]

I'm trying to remove the commas from this data set so they can be converted to `int` and be summed up all but I can't seem to find any way to do it without introducing spaces to the number values.

[image]

```
 parse = g.readlines()[8:]
 for x in parse:
    val0 = x.strip(',')
    val = val0.split(" ")
    i15.append(val[1])
```

this is my current code trying to remove the commas.

Comment: Did you try `replace()` instead of `strip()`?

Comment: havent, i dont know how that works, im new to python

Comment: `x.replace(',','')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python parse comma-separated number into int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953746/python-parse-comma-separated-number-into-int)

Answer (score 0):

```py
parse = g.readlines()[8:]
for x in parse:
    val0 = x.replace(',' , '')
    val = val0.split(" ")
    i15.append(val[1])
```

Try this

Comment: ['ARMM', '\t', '\t60342768\t62928933\t72664072\n'] returns me this list

Comment: @noobiecoder.can you ping the entire code. so i could check.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Panda Data frame has been used

You can use below code to solve your problem

```html
df1['columnname'] = df1['columnname'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Hope this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think in first You need to correctly parse data before you will append it to your array where you want to have it as a String or Int or any other type.

Below my solution for your problem:

```
lines = g.readlines()
for line in lines:
  x = line[2:].strip('').replace('  ', ' ').replace(',' , '').split(' ') // extract numbers from string assuming that first two characters are always characters that identify the data in a row
  for elem in x:
    if elem.isnumeric(): // append only elements that have numeric values
      i.append(int(elem))
```