# How would calculate the average, in salaries= { "Ben" : '82,500', "Bob" : '83,750', "Mike": '90,000', "Ann" : '89,000', "Sue" : '80,000' }

Tags: python, dictionary

Im having issues iterating through the dictionary because of the quotation marks in the values, how would I calculate the average in a dicitonary like this?

I tried to use the map function to bypass the quotation marks but that didnt work

Comment: There are no quotation marks in those values.  However, they are strings, and they contain commas.  You just need to remove the commas using `.replace` and convert to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first remove the ',' character from the strings then convert them to `int` to perform the math. Python will coerce the int type once the ',' is removed but it is better to explicitly convert to catch any errors early.

```
salaries= { "Ben" : '82,500', "Bob" : '83,750', "Mike": '90,000', "Ann" : '89,000', "Sue" : '80,000' }
for k,v in salaries.items():
    salaries[k] = int(v.replace(',',''))
avg = sum(salaries.values())/len(salaries.values())
print(avg)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `locale` package can help you deal with converting strings with commas to integers ([see this post for more help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2954231/2922676)).

You can use the `map` function to convert your dictionary strings into an iterable of proper integers by applying the `locale.atoi` function to every value in the dictionary. Then you can use the `mean` function in the `statistics` package to compute the average of the list.

```py
import locale
from statistics import mean

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')

d = { "Ben" : '82,500', "Bob" : '83,750', "Mike": '90,000', "Ann" : '89,000', "Sue" : '80,000' }

avg = mean(map(locale.atoi, d.values()))
```

Keep in mind that you may have issues if you get data from Europe as they use commas and periods differently in numbers.

If you don't want to use `locale`, you can do a similar thing with a lambda that does a string replace in the map function.

```py
from statistics import mean

d = { "Ben" : '82,500', "Bob" : '83,750', "Mike": '90,000', "Ann" : '89,000', "Sue" : '80,000' }

avg = mean(map(lambda x: int(x.replace(',', '')), d.values()))
```