# What type of output does soup.find() give in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I am looking at the link for the song Blank Space by Taylor Swift. I am trying to isolate just the number of views. But I can't seem to get it to use as a number.

This is what it returns:

```
Taylor Swift - Blank Space - YouTube
[u'721,891,621']
```

It isn't really a number, because I get this error if I add a 1:

```
print pizza[0].contents +1
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

Here is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ORhEE9VVg"
page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
print unicode(soup.title.string)


pizza= soup.find_all("div",{"class","watch-view-count"})
print pizza[0].contents
```

Comment: It says it in the exception: `can only concatenate list to list`. Therefore `pizza[0].contents` is a list.

Comment: Where are you using `soup.find()`? You are using `soup.find_all()` then accessed an attribute one of results. The [`.content` attribute documenation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) tells you what type it is: a `list` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pizza[0].contents` is a list. It says it directly in the exception you encountered. This can be verified by checking `type(pizza[0].contents)`

If you are trying to use the first element of the lists, use the indexer as you did for `pizza`: `pizza[0].contents[0]`. You can verify the type of this element by checking `type(pizza[0].contents[0])`

If you need an integer, you can do the appropriate conversions afterwards. [There are several methods to convert your text to an integer when it has commas for thousands separators.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th)

Comment: The line:  "print pizza[0].contents[0]" Returns the following error: "TypeError: an integer is required"  The line: I was hoping I could isolate the just the string. Then I could use the method you suggested to make it an integer.

Comment: The line:"type(pizza[0].contents[0])" returns the value "<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>"

Comment: @user2859603: That is a BeautifulSoup type. [So now you can refer to the documentation to convert it to a unicode string.](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) Note the comment about calling `unicode` on that type: `unicode(pizza[0].contents[0])`