# How do I divide two input values in Python?

Tags: python, variables, input

I'm trying to make a program that would divide the amount of words in a story by the amount of chapters in order to get the amount of words per chapter. Here is the script:

```
chapters = float(input('Enter the number of chapters. '))
words = float(input('Enter the number of words. '))
var1 = float(input(words / chapters))
```

Everytime I run it, it allows me to enter the values, but after trying to calculate, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/Users/Hudson/Desktop/Fanfiction Word Calculator.py", line 2, in <module>
    words = float(input('Enter the number of words. '))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '253,685'
```

Any idea why? Is it because the number is too big? I haven't used Python in a year, so I forgot how to do this :p

Comment: try removing the comma before casting to float

Comment: I guess you don't need a input again in `var1 = float(input(words / chapters))`

Comment: See also [how to convert number with comma for thousands](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th)

Answer (score 0):

in last line you don't need input. I modified your code and run it without any error:

```
chapters = float(input('Enter the number of chapters. '))
words = float(input('Enter the number of words. '))
var1 = float(words / chapters)
```

Comment: I downvoted your answer but I was wrong in doing so. However I cannot remove the downvote unless you make an edit :-/

Answer (score -2):

Try 253.685 instead of 253,685

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions. They should be deleted since they don't help anybody.

Comment: Most likely the OP didn't want to enter 253.685 words but  253685