# How to convert negative string to integer in pandas?(how to handle "-")

Tags: python, string, pandas, int

**Here's my problem:** I have a column of numbers in `pandas.dataFrame`. But there are certain numbers that need to be converted because they might be `string`'s.

Here's how the column currently looks:

```
[1
 -1,650.00
 -3
 ...]
```

I want it all to be integers. My code was:

```
df['columnname'].astype(int)
```

However, when I convert `-1,650.00` to `integer` I'm getting an error. Even  when the code is

```
df['columnname'].astype(float)
df['columnname'].astype(int)
```

It still doesn't solve the problem. It says `could not convert string to float: -` and the "-" is still not handled.

Comment: it is because of the comma. remove the comma with something like `replace(',','')` and it should work

Comment: how did you create the df?

Comment: casting a string with commas to a number in Python has been discussed here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['columnname'].replace(',','').astype(float)
```

Or:

```
float(df['columnname'].replace(',',''))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and edit! I appreciate your help. But my key problem is that the "-" is still there. The error says: "could not convert string to float: -". Do you know what I can do if I want to keep the "-" in this number?

Comment: have you tryed `print type(float('-1650.00'.replace(',','')))` ? it returns `<type 'float'>`. @ShaoqingZhang

Answer (score 1):

Float numbers use a dot to separate the integral part from the decimal part, not commas. Your vector should look something like this:

```
[1,
-1650.00,
-3,
]
```