# How to parse all the values in a column of a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

DataFrame df has a column called amount

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['$3,000,000.00','$3,000.00', '$200.5', '$5.5'], columns = ['Amount'])
```

df:

```
 ID | Amount
 0  | $3,000,000.00
 1  | $3,000.00
 2  | $200.5
 3  | $5.5
```

I want to parse all the values in column amount and extract the amount as a number and ignore the decimal points. End result is DataFrame that looks like this:

```
 ID | Amount
 0  | 3000000
 1  | 3000
 2  | 200
 3  | 5
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with double casting by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['Amount'] = (df.Amount.str.replace(r'[\$,]', '').astype(float).astype(int))
print (df)
    Amount
0  3000000
1     3000
2      200
3        5
```

Answer (score 3):

Code -

```
import pandas as pd

def format_amount(x):
    x = x[1:].split('.')[0]
    return int(''.join(x.split(',')))

df = pd.DataFrame(['$3,000,000.00','$3,000.00', '$200.5', '$5.5'], columns =
        ['Amount'])

df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].apply(format_amount)

print(df)
```

Output -

```
    Amount
0  3000000
1     3000
2      200
3        5
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the map function on the column and reassign to the same column:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )

df.Amount = df.Amount.map(lambda s: int(locale.atof(s[1:])))
```

PS: This uses the code from [How do I use Python to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-tho) to convert a string representing a number with thousands separator to an int

Comment: I test it in version `pandas 0.18.2`,  `python: 3.5.1`.and  `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,000,000.00'`. I use `import locale
print (df.Amount.map(lambda s: int(locale.atof(s[1:]))))`. What can be problem? Maybe pandas API was changed. Maybe someone try to test too.

Comment: You need `locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8' )` before you try to parse the number.

Comment: I try it and now `Error: unsupported locale setting`.

Comment: But for me works [`locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'english_USA' )`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12746073/2901002).