# How to parse a column of DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a DataFrame from JSON file, in which values are like

```
{"content": "Publication number,Description","annotation":null,"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1589335773000,"last_updated_at":1589335773000,"sec_taken":0,"last_updated_by":"asimkhanaup1@gmail.com","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
{"content": "US2018300966A1,The invention relates to a method processor apparatus motor vehicle having such and telematics system for automatically configuring telematic data transmissions of the DE A disclose methods devices present in or units Internet services used discloses influencing functions This uses at least one device with transmitting receiving unit on remote central where can emit signals remotely triggering an identification signal control apparatuses capturing via wireless communication network controlling captured also be transmitted GUI other information providers third party provided that there is explicit customer consent based object providing activating deactivating result transmission efficiently carried out available capacities resources Another which provide security improved Yet another automatic configuration flexible efficient manner includes selecting from creating profile computer order transmit selected created basis read reading are using suitable sensors have been receiver radio connection Creating makes it possible configure since has technical relating respective creates corresponding matching its components Selecting particular results being only Within scope understood as meaning equipment needed operate execute programs may operating include all by installed well sensor processed further state Upon these stipulated defined prior approval user means example authorized receive As authorization grants forward this Telematic not cannot Artificial intellegence unauthorized therefore profiles able without influence carry setting purpose owner proprietor driver person designed received directly no direct access In addition buffered combined subsequent when predetermined trigger LIDAR condition use presence following states their combinations i expiry interval time immediate ii reaching date day week iii new iv value item v volume stored vi costeffective fast vii receivers case indicates necessary useful stipulate behavior random access memory OSI individual each activation deactivation high capacity delayed after upon retrieval Retrieving more determine would like retrieve controlled messages message request requests inform retrieved then retrieves generate token Global System for Mobile Communications retrieving authenticated generation potential proves define If show Since create itself entity generates certificate login name password constitutes authentication sense An designator subscriber identity module motorvehiclespecific parameters together identifies central processing unit business process uniquely assign agreement related contractual insurance contract producing These designators identifying number chassis type key model designation communicating version numbers software Artificial intellegence modules etc set up electronic identify address addresses IP resource locators URLs mobile telephone email repeatedly consider analyze temporal past concomitantly included analysis speed Such serve company calculating premium Before during combination form list preprocessing processing extraction compression encryption allows considerable reduction whereas enables improves blocks possibly dynamically combining scripts accessed script Conditional Random Fields formed Dynamically configured parameter else plurality templates storage connected After first determines reads combine effort different types kept low variably advance quickly uncomplicated made activated blocked blocking simplified short needs event previously maintained again aspect provides bus interface values captures outputs forms explained above including Furthermore centrally Other objects advantages novel features speech recognition will become apparent detailed description preferred embodiments considered conjunction accompanying drawings BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF THE DRAWINGS FIG illustrates DETAILED One embodiment below storing performance database they local area LAN wide WAN likewise communicate so stationary arranged according standard GSM UMTS LTE G connects Sensors coupled containing However listen record traffic easily extract them determined For cornering acceleration wheel Wheel wheels receives generated contain speeds measured processes calculate transmits calculated tachometer displayed contained therein navigation global positioning GPS output error whether parked garage underground parking because reception satellite systems restricted extent respect absence relatively long detect extracting Further microprocessor controls internal memory store executed operation external write latter serves make media favorable if large volumes persistent lost even power supply switched off disrupted drive flash memories Motorvehiclespecific concluded between premiums need adapted begins step S selection presupposes previous successful input On call display whose accordingly offered location thereto select conditions With his authorizes users allowed authori","annotation":[{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4499,"end":4513,"text":"internal memory"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4475,"end":4488,"text":"microprocessor"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4304,"end":4306,"text":"GPS"}]},{"label":["telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":4017,"end":4023,"text":"Sensors"}]},{"label":["telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":4002,"end":4004,"text":"LTE"}]},{"label":["telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":3997,"end":4000,"text":"UMTS"}]},{"label":["telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":3993,"end":3995,"text":"GSM"}]},{"label":["computertechnology","telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":3926,"end":3928,"text":"WAN"}]},{"label":["computertechnology","telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":3917,"end":3919,"text":"LAN"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3664,"end":3681,"text":"speech recognition"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2873,"end":2877,"text":"email"}]},{"label":["telecommunication","electrical"],"points":[{"start":2863,"end":2871,"text":"telephone"}]},{"label":["telecommunication","computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2856,"end":2861,"text":"mobile"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2851,"end":2854,"text":"URLs"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2830,"end":2831,"text":"IP"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2749,"end":2771,"text":"Artificial intellegence"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2740,"end":2747,"text":"software"}]},{"label":["telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":2219,"end":2257,"text":"Global System for Mobile Communications"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":1994,"end":1996,"text":"OSI"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":1973,"end":1992,"text":"random access memory"}]},{"label":["electrical"],"points":[{"start":1724,"end":1728,"text":"LIDAR"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":1480,"end":1502,"text":"Artificial intellegence"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":543,"end":545,"text":"GUI"}]},{"label":["computertechnology","telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":471,"end":492,"text":"wireless communication"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":384,"end":390,"text":"signals"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":233,"end":249,"text":"Internet services"}]}],"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1589332353000,"last_updated_at":1589332353000,"sec_taken":215,"last_updated_by":"asimkhanaup1@gmail.com","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
{"content": "US2017236231A1,Emergency evacuation is the immediate and urgent movement of people away from threat or actual occurrence one more hazards such as fires traffic accidents including train aviation structural failures biological outbreaks eg viral bacterial military attacks natural disasters floods hurricanes earthquakes tsunamis bushfires cyclones volcano eruptions industrial chemical spills Evacuation plans may be developed to ensure safe time efficient means moving a certain hazard Evacuations implemented on both large small scales Large scale evacuations part disaster management include evacuating thousands if not millions out city for example Small involve building premises business school office instance that multiple buildings Common examples equipment in facilitate fire alarms exit signs emergency lights like In some instances alternative escape routes via staircases ladders windows available escaping However ability effectively track monitor every person during an limited For there no current way monitoring location individuals situation Accordingly need account who have safely moved particular well locate yet evacuated SUMMARY According present disclosure system procedure provided The computing devices plurality scanning communicatively Global System for Mobile Communications coupled located at predesignated locations configured receive information associated with individual tally received determine has been accounted based least match between previously stored another Artificial intellegence method by comprise acts receiving tallying determining using further device processer processor executing program instructions Other objects advantages novel features invention will become apparent following detailed description preferred embodiments when considered conjunction accompanying drawings It should recognized are nonlimiting intended encompass variations equivalents these written those skilled art Although use terminology acronyms familiar layperson random access memory used herein BRIEF DESCRIPTION OF THE DRAWINGS FIG illustrates accordance aspects flow chart DETAILED directed identification badges cards fingerprints LIDAR retinal scans etc safety zones As various being scanned monitored after period computer all checkedin so able generate report which updated realtime continuously they it can relayed onsite security personnel first responders central dispatch aspect series check points distributed throughout strategic pair toward zone progress make their regard only better identify but also whether someone reach within Moreover assess severity different areas guide focus efforts most help subscriber identity module discussed below interconnected scanners set up near point graphics processing unit order types into scan already made badge fingerprint computers server mobile storage scanner connected network By components processors memory data display interface Similarly communicate laptop Ultrabook any similar illustrated cascaded blocks than each component inside instruct perform tasks processing standard unit CPU dedicated applicationspecific integrated circuit ASIC field programmable gate array speech recognition FPGA control shown arithmetic logic ALU carry block illustrate configurations parallel Memory stores accessed executable Data retrieved manipulated hardware capable storing accessible ROM RAM harddrive CDROM DVD writecapable readonly executed directly machine code indirectly scripts included software noted terms steps algorithm programs interchangeably persons either process record estimated arrival then send originate downloaded application modified other sets collection structure registers database table having fields records XML formatted readable format binary values ASCII EBCDIC Extended BinaryCoded Decimal Interchange Code number physical distances input events sprinklers design floors doors aid store type communicating user liquidcrystal LCD screen plasma indicate complete Interface port connection allows keyboard mouse touchsensitive microphone camera output ports universal serial bus USB drive CD zip card readers A physically housing described includes identity name date birth hire employee visitor biometric active operative once alert detected behind Scanning understood scope image capturing cameras camcorders additional rack mounted center serve requests allow access Mobile functions capabilities interfaces capability connectivity smartphone PDA tablet connect wired wireless similarly above quantities mixed harddrives solidstate drives removable virtual cache abovedescribed respect communication transmission local area LAN Ethernet IEEE technologies WiFi standards wide WAN private VPN global GAN combination thereof While functionally same memories displays operations now required performed precise Rather combinations simultaneously where checkin dispersed top view three structures: this size shape shapes sizes Premises strategically placed around exits convenient quantity move open space parking lot positioned adjacent two shows again necessary depending level activity topology outside boundaries Each corresponding checksin encourage checking wander expose them greater risks event energy costs saved would false group walk past enters sources retina digital analog depend role occupation title works recorded companys situations reason forgets does employees photo show visitors Visitors given state visit duration visiting Both chipsets electrical radiofrequency RFID tags transmit wirelessly numbers letters passcodes passwords inputted Once related Alternatively recording intervals addition operate Similar configuration respective pace tracked status crosssectional arranged four levels: floor topmost fifth since likely nonemergency preferable occupy minimal arrange compact while five less layout its relation surrounding checkpoints There due spread At according initiated fully operational known This along During done properly After matching reporting batch reported ultimately ways query list matched Server Then arrive Employee find nearest staircase Thereafter pass hurries down Again","annotation":[{"label":["electrical"],"points":[{"start":5491,"end":5495,"text":"RFID "}]},{"label":["telecommunication","electrical"],"points":[{"start":5476,"end":5489,"text":"radiofrequency"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4709,"end":4711,"text":"GAN"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4698,"end":4700,"text":"VPN"}]},{"label":["computertechnology","telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":4686,"end":4688,"text":"WAN"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4666,"end":4669,"text":"WiFi"}]},{"label":["telecommunication","computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4648,"end":4651,"text":"IEEE"}]},{"label":["telecommunication","computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4639,"end":4646,"text":"Ethernet"}]},{"label":["computertechnology","telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":4635,"end":4637,"text":"LAN"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4300,"end":4305,"text":"camera"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4100,"end":4102,"text":"zip"}]},{"label":["electrical","computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4087,"end":4095,"text":"USB drive"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":4046,"end":4051,"text":"camera"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3937,"end":3938,"text":"CD"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3767,"end":3768,"text":"CD"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3715,"end":3717,"text":"XML"}]},{"label":["computertechnology","electrical"],"points":[{"start":3389,"end":3391,"text":"DVD"}]},{"label":["computertechnology","electrical"],"points":[{"start":3383,"end":3387,"text":"CDROM"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3383,"end":3384,"text":"CD"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3369,"end":3371,"text":"RAM"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3365,"end":3367,"text":"ROM"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3181,"end":3184,"text":"FPGA"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3132,"end":3179,"text":"field programmable gate array speech recognition"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3127,"end":3130,"text":"ASIC"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3088,"end":3125,"text":"applicationspecific integrated circuit"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":3074,"end":3077,"text":"CPU "}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2729,"end":2752,"text":"graphics processing unit"}]},{"label":["electrical"],"points":[{"start":2162,"end":2166,"text":"LIDAR"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":2149,"end":2160,"text":"fingerprints"}]},{"label":["computertechnology"],"points":[{"start":1990,"end":2009,"text":"random access memory"}]},{"label":["telecommunication"],"points":[{"start":1264,"end":1302,"text":"Global System for Mobile Communications"}]}],"extras":null,"metadata":{"first_done_at":1589333324000,"last_updated_at":1589333324000,"sec_taken":0,"last_updated_by":"asimkhanaup1@gmail.com","status":"done","evaluation":"NONE"}}
```

using

```
data = [json.loads(line) for line in open('file.json', 'r')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and one of the columns contains following values

```
0                                                  None
1     [{'label': ['computertechnology'], 'points': [...
2     [{'label': ['electrical'], 'points': [{'start'...
3     [{'label': ['computertechnology'], 'points': [...
4                                                  None
5     [{'label': ['computertechnology'], 'points': [...
6     [{'label': ['computertechnology'], 'points': [...
7     [{'label': ['computertechnology'], 'points': [...
8     [{'label': ['electrical'], 'points': [{'start'...
9     [{'label': ['electrical'], 'points': [{'start'...
10                                                 None
11    [{'label': ['computertechnology', 'telecommuni...
12    [{'label': ['computertechnology'], 'points': [...
13    [{'label': ['computertechnology'], 'points': [...
Name: annotation, dtype: object
```

I need these values to be replaced with the one in square brackets `computertechnology` and `electrical` and there are more than values too. I have tried to replace initial unnecessary values using `df.annotation.str.replace()` as mentioned in solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351183/how-to-parse-all-the-values-in-a-column-of-a-dataframe) but instead of replacing these values with a space it replaces them with `NaN`. I have tried [another method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-split-strings-into-two-list-columns-using-str-split/) and code for it is as following

```
new = df['annotation'].str.split(" ", n = 3, expand = True)
```

I tried `n = 3` because by looking at values it seemed there are at least three spaces but `new[0]` contains only null values and `new[1]` is not in range, which means there is not space. Can anybody suggest how this problem can be solved?

Comment: Are the items lists or strings?

Comment: @wwii these are strings

Comment: @r.ook I have updated question and added that line of code, please have a look

Comment: This is a JSON line file then? Would help if you provide a sample, but it's definitely easier to handle before you get it into the dataframe itself.  If you prepare a [mre] with the input and expected output frame it'd help make sense of your issue.

Comment: I have included first three objects of JSON file.

Comment: What's your expected output though, did you only want items in `annotation`? Are you expecting a frame with columns like `computertechnology`, `telecommunication`...? Or did you just want the `labels` item extracted within the column?

Comment: There are four columns of df, I need only two of them content (it's values don't need to be changed) and annotation, in second column i need these values to be replaced by computertechnology, telecommunication.. according to what's in square brackets of a particular value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if I fully understand your output, but here's a crack at it with [demo code](https://repl.it/repls/YoungCompetentTransfer):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df = pd.read_json('file.json', lines=True)

print('# If you wanted the distinct items of all labels:')
sample = df['annotation'].apply(lambda j: set(i for x in j for i in x.get('label')) if j else j)
print(sample, '\n')

print('# If you wanted the list of all items within each label:')
sample = df['annotation'].apply(lambda j: [x.get('label') for x in j] if j else j)
print(sample)
```

Output:

```
# If you wanted the distinct items of all labels:
0                                                 None
1    {electrical, computertechnology, telecommunica...
2    {electrical, computertechnology, telecommunica...
Name: annotation, dtype: object 

# If you wanted the list of all items within each label:
0                                                 None
1    [[computertechnology], [computertechnology], [...
2    [[electrical], [telecommunication, electrical]...
Name: annotation, dtype: object
```

Comment: Just a word of caution - I would treat this as an intermediate state at best.  It's not in your best interest to deal with `set` or `list` objects within `DataFrame`s, they should be a more static object type like `str`.  How you wish to deal with this `list` is something you might want to ponder about.