# Formatting a string as a price in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, decimal, string-formatting

Given a string `$29,656.9`, using python 2.7, what is the best way to convert it to `$29,656.90`

That is to say, what is the simplest way ensure that a "price" string always has 2 digits after the decimal place while leaving the `$` and any `,`'s intact?

My first thought was to convert the str to a float and use the `:.2f` format helper, but that doesnt work easily due to the `$` and `,` in the string

```
price = '$29,656.9'
print('{0:.2f}'.format(float(price)))
```

Of course, this gives:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "python", line 2, in
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '$29,656.9'

**Note:** I do not control the input. It is not possible for me to get the raw float value and format it properly to begin with

Comment: You'll want to parse the string into a number first, that is, remove the dollar sign (`lstrip`, or just `price[1:]`), then convert it to float. Python does not handle units for you, just plain numbers (but some packages can do this for you).

Comment: @Evert, both of those would leave the comma though right? Then I'd still have to remove that? Is there really no better way?

Comment: Not much of a better way (e.g., nothing like `strptime` that I know of). As for the comma, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th

Comment: @Evert could you tell me exactly what `[1:]` is doing? (I assume it just removes the first char? but Im not familiar with that syntax)

Comment: @Evert that's a shame, I'd have to then put the `$` and `,` back after Im done. Oh we'll, I guess I'll just use a regex replace then

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yes, it strips the first character. The syntax is called [slicing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: @Selcuk thanks on both counts :) dupe question is just what I needed