# invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,303'

Tags: django

I get get error invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,303' and it shows the blow code at fault. The old data works fine, its just for new stuff i add to the database. Any ideas?

```
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    cart = self.get_object()
    item_id = request.GET.get("item")
    delete_item = request.GET.get("delete", False)
    flash_message = ""
    item_added = False
    if item_id:
                    item_instance = get_object_or_404(Variation, id=item_id) ...
        qty = request.GET.get("qty", 1)
        try:
            if int(qty) < 1:
                delete_item = True
        except:
            raise Http404
```

Comment: Is the comma here being used as the decimal mark? What do you expect to do if there are decimal places?

Comment: Related: [How do I use Python to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1779288/1324033), but use django forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why you should use django forms instead of pulling data direct off `request.GET` or `request.POST`. Django forms provide you with data validation which helps you avoid this kind of thing. The problem is the extra ',' in your supposed int.

```
int('1,303')
```

Will produce the error above. The following will not:

```
int('1,303'.replace(',',''))
```

So the obvious remedy then is to pass your int through such a filter.

```
item_instance = get_object_or_404(Variation, id=int(item_id.replace(',',''))
```

Comment: In european countries, `,` is used instead of `.` as a decimal point, so this may not achieve the same result