# Convert a number using atof

Tags: python, python-3.5

In `Python 3.5`, I'd like to convert a German number string to a float using `locale.atof` with the following code:

---

```
import locale
from locale import atof
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

number = atof('17.907,08')
```

However, this raises a `ValueError`:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '17.907.08'
```

---

Why? Isn't this exactly what `atof()` was made for?

Comment: Is your number `'17.907.08'`, as in the error, or `'17.907,08''` as in your code?

Comment: @tobias_k: The latter, it is `17.907,08`, the other format is only the error message.

Comment: To be clear: the claim is that the error message shows the value differently from the source code? That seems hard to believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can't have more than one dot (`.`) or comma (`,`) in your number** since both of these symbols are used by `atof()` to separate the decimal part of your number from its integer part.

Since the dots are not needed for Python to correctly represent your number, you should remove them and only keep the comma:

```
import locale
from locale import atof
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE')

string_nb = '17.907,08'
string_nb = string_nb.replace('.', '')
number = atof(string)
```

Comment: It works and answers my question - but how to distinguish which part to remove? I have several numbers, English and German ones.

Comment: @Jan: What is the difference between English and German numbers? Does `17.907,08` in German become `17,907.08` in English? Or `17907.08`?

Comment: `$1,000,000` is one million in English while it would be `1.000.000` in German.

Comment: In Python 3.10 this manipulation is no longer needed. `atof('17.907,08')` works.

Answer (score 1):

Just for future reference - this is what I ended up using:

```
import locale
from locale import atof

def convert(string, thousands_delim = '.', abbr = 'de_DE.UTF-8'):
    ''' Converts a string to float '''

    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, abbr)
    try:
        number = atof("".join(string.split(thousands_delim)))
    except ValueError:
        number = None

    return number
```

---

You call it like

```
number = convert('17.907,08')
print(number)
# 17907.08
```

... or for English numbers:

```
number = convert('1,000,000', abbr = 'en_US')
print(number)
# 1000000.0
```

Comment: You no longer need that, `atof('17.907,08')` just works in Python 3.10.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.10 the works as expected

```
>>> from locale import atof
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE' )
'de_DE'
>>> atof('17.907,08')
17907.08
```

Using string manipulations to parse decimals is very fragile and should be avoided when possible. Using the wrong replacement could convert decimals to thousands and vice versa