# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11,440'

Tags: python, python-3.x

This code prints out the tasklist of the OS. However, the following error is seen when it is run. Is there an easy solution to this problem?

```
  "mem_usage":int(m.group(5).decode('ascii', 'ignore'))})
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '11,440'
```

Code:

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_output

def get_processes_running():
    """
    Takes tasklist output and parses the table into a dict
    """
    tasks = check_output(['tasklist']).decode('cp866', 
'ignore').split("\r\n")
    p = []
    for task in tasks:
        m = re.match(b'(.*?)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(.*?)\\s.*', task.encode())
        if m is not None:
            p.append({"image":m.group(1).decode(),
                     "pid":int(m.group(2).decode()),
                    "session_name":m.group(3).decode(),
                    "session_num":int(m.group(4).decode()),
                    "mem_usage":int(m.group(5).decode('ascii', 'ignore'))})
    return p


def test():
    print(*[line.decode('cp866', 'ignore') for line in Popen('tasklist', stdout=PIPE).stdout.readlines()])

    lstp = get_processes_running()
    for p in lstp:
        print(p)
    return

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: For what it's worth, if you want to list details about running processes in Python it would behoove you to use the very powerful [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package. It works on Windows too!

Comment: A possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-tho

Answer (score 5):

I haven't fully read your code, but from your error, I would suggest using the `.replace` method on the string that you are trying to convert to an integer to remove all commas.

For instance, at the moment, you are doing something like:

```
>>> int('123,456')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '123,456'
```

which throws an error due to the comma marks. Simply remove all commas to fix this:

```
>>> int('123,456'.replace(',',''))
123456
```

Comment: tasklist uses a strange comma formatting to print processes memory. removing the comma allows to get the proper value

Answer (score 0):

See this:-

`>>> int('23ds4')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '23ds4'`

This is the same case as yours. That character `","` is also not an integer in that provided string. So it is not a valid argument.

You better replace those commas from your integer contained string:-

```
>>> s = '11,234,234'
>>> s.replace(',','')
'11234234'
```