# How can I transform a value after it was extracted?

Tags: scrapy, scrapinghub, portia

I am using Portia to extract info from a page. However, one of the values extracted is not in a format that I can use.

More specifically, I want to extract a numeric value which uses a dot instead of a comma to denote thousands e.g. "1.000" instead of "1,000".

Is it possible to extract and then transform with Portia? I can set a regex to extract numbers but is it possible to replace them too?

What I'm doing now is that I export the data to csv and then use `sed` to replace the numbers in question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check: [How do I use Python to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-th)

```
import locale
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8' )
locale.atoi('1.000')
# 1000
```

Basically it's string to number with the correct format mask

Comment: Hey Thomas. Thanks for your answer. However, Portia is a UI which allows me from avoid to write code to crawl a page. So I was wondering if there was a way via the UI itself to do that. There is a way to declare a regex which is used to extract a value from a string but there isn't a way to replace/transform that value.

Comment: Probably in the UI there is a convert method as well. Should be a standard function