# Converting dictionary value from tuple to a list (python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

So I have a `data.txt` file that holds information about a car:

> CAR|PRICE|RPM
>
> TOYOTA|21,000|3,600
>
> HONDA|19,000|4,000

And by passing this data file into the function `createCarDictionary` I was able to create a dictionary that creates the car brand as the key and the values as the remaining information in the txt file stored as tuples:

```
dict1 = {}

def createCarDictionary(datafile):
    for line in datafile.splitlines():
        key, value, value2 = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
        dict1[key] = value, value2
    return dict1

datafile = open('data.txt', 'r').read()

createCarDictionary(datafile)
print(dict1)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'CAR': ('PRICE', 'RPM'), 'TOYOTA': ('21,000', '3,600'), 'HONDA': ('19,000', '4,000')}
```

So my question(s) is/are:
What must I add to the function to ***1)*** remove the commas in the numbers and ***2)*** convert the tuple values into a list, so I can manipulate them later.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-tho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply surround your values with brackets to make them a `list` instead of `tuple`, and use `replace()` to remove all ',' from every line.

```
dict1 = {}

def createCarDictionary(datafile):
    for line in datafile.splitlines():
        line = line.replace(',', '')
        key, value, value2 = map(str.strip, line.split('|'))
        dict1[key] = [value, value2]
    return dict1

datafile = open('data.txt', 'r').read()

createCarDictionary(datafile)
print(dict1)
```

Output:

```
{'HONDA': ['19000', '4000'], 'TOYOTA': ['21000', '3600'], 'CAR': ['PRICE', 'RPM']}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, change:

`dict1[key] = value, value2`

To:

`dict1[key] = [int(i.replace(',','')) for i in (value1,value2)]`

---

But you could also use **pandas** if you are open to new libraries:

```
import pandas as pd

filedata = '''\
CAR|PRICE|RPM
TOYOTA|21,000|3,600
HONDA|19,000|4,000'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(filedata) # change this to the path of your file
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep='|', thousands=',')
d = dict(zip(df.pop('CAR'), df.values.tolist()))
#d = df.set_index('CAR').to_dict('i') # OR MAYBE THIS?
print(d)
```

Returns:

```
{'TOYOTA': [21000, 3600], 'HONDA': [19000, 4000]}
```