# Ignoring character when converting

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using the command:

```
cena_postov=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'td_')]/td[11]/a[1]/span/span")
for spisok_cen in cena_postov:
  print(spisok_cen.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

I get a text list. I want to convert it to a number using

```
if int(spisok_cen.get_attribute('textContent'))<=10 and int(spisok_cen.get_attribute('textContent'))>=12000:
 print('anything')
```

but the symbol `'` bothers me.
I get an error `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ": 6'000`
how to make python ignore this character?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` method to remove unnecessary `'`:

```
if int(spisok_cen.get_attribute('textContent').replace("'", ""))<=10 and int(spisok_cen.get_attribute('textContent').replace("'", ""))>=12000:
    print('anything')
```

Also you can find solution with `locale` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-do-i-use-python-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-tho).

Comment: I added a couple more .replace("'", "").replace(":", "").replace(" ", "") and it worked. Thank you, I will read the second method later.