# How do I convert a symbol within a dataframe to a float in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and working on string manipulation

I have a dataframe

```
df['Installs']
Out[22]: 
0           10,000+
1          500,000+
2        5,000,000+
3       50,000,000+
4          100,000+
5           50,000+
```

How do I remove the "+" and convert the string in the df to float?

My input:

df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].str.replace('+','',regex=True).astype(float)

However I get an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '10,000'
```

How can I edit my code such that I get 10,000.0 as my output and so on for the other values instead of 10,000+

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but you should find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato helpful.

Comment: Also, try to remove comma before calling `astype(float)`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `,` and `+` to empty `string`:

```
df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].str.replace('[,+]','').astype(float)
#alternative
#df['Installs'] = df['Installs'].replace('[,+]','', regex=True).astype(float)
print (df)
     Installs
0     10000.0
1    500000.0
2   5000000.0
3  50000000.0
4    100000.0
5     50000.0
```