# How to convert object type to integer type with ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,156,624,900'?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a data set on suicides, part of which includes a `gdp_for_year` column. However, the column is of `object` type and understandably needs to be an `int`. This is the error I receive:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-ec740fbd9849> in <module>
      2 suicides.info()
      3 
----> 4 suicides['gdp_for_year'] = suicides['gdp_for_year'].astype('int')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
   5696         else:
   5697             # else, only a single dtype is given
-> 5698             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
   5699             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5700 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    580 
    581     def astype(self, dtype, copy: bool = False, errors: str = "raise"):
--> 582         return self.apply("astype", dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors)
    583 
    584     def convert(self, **kwargs):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py in apply(self, f, filter, **kwargs)
    440                 applied = b.apply(f, **kwargs)
    441             else:
--> 442                 applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    443             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    444 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors)
    623             vals1d = values.ravel()
    624             try:
--> 625                 values = astype_nansafe(vals1d, dtype, copy=True)
    626             except (ValueError, TypeError):
    627                 # e.g. astype_nansafe can fail on object-dtype of strings

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\dtypes\cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    872         # work around NumPy brokenness, #1987
    873         if np.issubdtype(dtype.type, np.integer):
--> 874             return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
    875 
    876         # if we have a datetime/timedelta array of objects

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.astype_intsafe()

**ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2,156,624,900'**
```

[Dataframe info() and head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPqna.jpg)

Does anyone have suggestions on what I can do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string

```
'2,156,624,900'
```

contains comma's. You can't automatically convert this string to an integer. You would first have to remove the comma's. You can do so by:

```
int('2,156,624,900'.replace(',', ''))
```

So, in your case, you would either want to follow some of the more elaborate locale settings linked in the comment under your post or apply this `replace` function on the whole column first, and then convert it to `int`.