# How to convert a string that represents a money value to a Python Decimal object considering the country's local currency?

Tags: python, decimal, locale, currency

I need to convert a string to `Decimal()` in Python, but it can have the characters "." and "," because of the Brazilian format, it could be something like "80.255,00". I used the string's `replace()` method like this `str_value = str_value.strip().replace (". "," ").replace (", ",". ")` and then converted it to Decimal like this `value = Decimal(str_value)`, but I was wondering if there is a pythonic way of doing this, because using replace twice and then Decimal doesn't seem like the most beautiful way to do this, besides if the string is wrong like "80,255,00", "80,255.00" or "80.255.00" this will not work correctly :( In addition, the value may have more places after the comma, such as "80.255,0045".

Thanks to anyone who helps me

Comment: Don't replace anything. It will never work. *Parse* the string using the correct regional settings. Half the world uses `,` as the decimal separator, China and India use `.` (the US does too, but that's 1/10th of the other two). If you try to replace separators you have at least a 50% chance to get it wrong resulting either in errors or worse, wrong results

Comment: You can use either `locale.atof` or a library like `babel` to parse a string using a specific locale, with eg `parse_decimal('1.099,98', locale='de')`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato This post has similar problem.

Comment: Thank you very much, you guys helped me a lot.