# Extracting Digit as numeric but not into a list in Python

Tags: python, numeric, digits

I am trying to extract numbers from a text using the code below:

```
>>> import re
>>> text="Technical Details Item Weight381 g Product Dimensions29.8 x 8.2 x 5.4 cm Best Sellers Rank 1,239,929 in Toys & Games (See top 100)"
>>> re.findall('Best Sellers Rank (.+?) in',str(text))
['1,239,929']
```

The output of the code is saved as a list. However, my goal is to extract the number as a numeric object (i.e. 1239929).

Answer (score 0):

You almost there

```
import re
text="Technical Details Item Weight381 g Product Dimensions29.8 x 8.2 x 5.4 cm Best Sellers Rank 1,239,929 in Toys & Games (See top 100)"
print(re.findall('Best Sellers Rank (.+?) in',str(text))[0])
```

Gives #

```
1,239,929
```

If you want to be a single number it is possible a duplicate as @mkrieger1 mentioned apply rest method [How to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato)

Comment: it will be string type

Comment: Yeah, the goal is probably to extract numbers: "my goal is to extract the numbers as numeric objects.", I've combined your answer with mkrieger1's.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text="Technical Details Item Weight381 g Product Dimensions29.8 x 8.2 x 5.4 cm Best Sellers Rank 1,239,929 in Toys & Games (See top 100)"
```

If you want a single integer then:

```
int(''.join(re.findall('Best Sellers Rank (.+?) in',str(text))[0].split(',')))

#output
1239929
```

Comment: Actually, I believe it's 1239929 (1_239_929)