# Converting DBF numeric-like column to string CSV

Tags: python, csv, type-conversion, dbf

I need to convert DBF file with numeric values into csv file as strings

DBF file column contains numeric data:

```
NUMBER,C,12 | ...
584413
079711
478293
000865
```

I use this python function to convert it to csv:

```
from dbfread import DBF
def dbf_to_csv(dbf_table_pth):#Input a dbf, output a csv, same name, same path, except extension
    csv_fn = dbf_table_pth[:-4]+ ".csv" #Set the csv file name
    table = DBF(dbf_table_pth)# table variable is a DBF object
    with open(csv_fn, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline = '') as f:# create a csv file, fill it with dbf content
        writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='excel')
        writer.writerow(table.field_names)# write the column name
        for record in table:# write the rows
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
    return csv_fn# return the csv name
```

It leads to csv-result below, when I open it in notepad:

```
NUMBER, ...
"584413,0", ...
"79711,0", ...
"478293,0", ...
"865,0", ...
```

How can I improve func to get results like this?:

```
NUMBER, ...
584413, ...
079711, ...
478293, ...
000865, ...
```

Comment: Looks like there is a locale issue where the decimal marker is `,`. From this question [Convert locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-number-if-it-has-commas-in-it-as-thousands-separato) maybe something like: `import locale locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8' ) int(locale.atof('584413,0')) 584413`. You would have to transform each row. Maybe use custom parser as shown here [Custom field](https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#custom-field-types)

Comment: I can't replicate, so you will need to provide more information about your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on guess of how the data is formatted in your DBF table.
Use `FieldParser` from here [Custom Field Types](https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#custom-field-types) to change the output for the `NUMBER` field. Uses `locale` to set to locale that recognizes `,` as decimal marker and then `locale.atof` to convert to float and `int()` to convert to integer.

```
import locale
from dbfread import DBF, FieldParser

locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'de_DE.UTF-8' )

tbl_db = DBF('test.dbf')

for row in tbl_db:
    print(row)

OrderedDict([('NUMBER', '3298,0'), ('NAME', 'test')])
OrderedDict([('NUMBER', '6214'), ('NAME', 'dog')])
OrderedDict([('NUMBER', '9418,0'), ('NAME', 'cat')])

class NumericConvert(FieldParser):
    def parseC(self, field, data):
        if field.name == "NUMBER":
            return int(locale.atof(data.decode()))
        else:
            return data

tbl_db = DBF('test.dbf', parserclass=NumericConvert)

for row in tbl_db:
    print(row)

OrderedDict([('NUMBER', 3298), ('NAME', b'test      ')])
OrderedDict([('NUMBER', 6214), ('NAME', b'dog       ')])
OrderedDict([('NUMBER', 9418), ('NAME', b'cat       ')])
```