# How can I convert a string with dot and comma into a float in Python

Tags: python, type-conversion

How can I convert a string like `123,456.908` to float `123456.908` in Python?

---

<sub>For `int`s, see [How to convert a string to a number if it has commas in it as thousands separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779288), although the techniques are essentially the same.</sub>

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use the `locale` module - everything else is just a very nasty hack that will get you into trouble in the future.

Comment: The proper `locale`way is also a very good way to shoot you in the foot if you plan to use your program on several operating systems (like Windows and flavors of Linux), which have different locale formats or even might need you to install a locale that supports your chosen format...

Comment: I updated my old `locale`-based answer to explain these issues comprehensively.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Just remove the `,` with `replace()`:

```
float("123,456.908".replace(',',''))
```

Comment: this depends on locale.
9 988 776,65 € in France
9.988.776,65 € in Germany
$9,988,776.65 in the United States

Comment: If you are writing constants in the source code and want to use commas to make it more readable then this is the way to go rather than locale which would then make the code fail in another location.   
```python
cd_size = float("737,280,000".replace(',',''))```   

(I actually used int)

Comment: If you are writing a string literal constant in the source code and then explicitly converting it to integer or float, that's a sign of something wrong with the design. But even if it can be defended - just temporarily set the locale to the one the code is written in, for that context, and then restore the context appropriate to your users when handling user input. That's why there is `setlocale` in the first place.

Comment: do not do this, it allows for things like "123,,,,345"

Comment: This extremely dangerous replacement would [fail in half of the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#/media/File:DecimalSeparator.svg), the other half being China. And the US. Europe, Africa, Russia, South America, use `,` as the decimal separator

Comment: @hum3 PEP 515 introduced underscores for numeric literals. In Python 3.6 you can just write 737_280_000 instead of doing string manipulations to make things more readable.

Comment: Thank @Malcolm  I think PEP-515 is a better solution if you have control over the text.  In my case I didn't as was getting someone elses input.

Answer (score 209):

### Using the localization services

#### The default locale

The standard library `locale` module is Python's interface to C-based localization routines.

The basic usage is:

```
import locale
locale.atof('123,456')
```

In locales where `,` is treated as a thousands separator, this would return `123456.0`; in locales where it is treated as a decimal point, it would return `123.456`.

However, **by default, this will not work**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/locale.py", line 326, in atof
    return func(delocalize(string))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '123,456'
```

This is because by default, the program is "in a locale" that has **nothing to do with** the platform the code is running on, but is instead defined by the POSIX standard. As the documentation explains:

> Initially, when a program is started, the locale is the `C` locale, no matter what the user’s preferred locale is. There is one exception: the `LC_CTYPE` category is changed at startup to set the current locale encoding to the user’s preferred locale encoding. The program must explicitly say that it wants the user’s preferred locale settings for other categories by calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, '')`.

That is: aside from making a note of the system's default setting for the preferred character encoding in text files (nowadays, this will likely be UTF-8), by default, the `locale` module will interpret data the same way that Python itself does (via a locale named `C`, after the C programming language). `locale.atof` will do the same thing as `float` passed a string, and similarly `locale.atoi` will mimic `int`.

#### Using a locale from the environment

Making the `setlocale` call mentioned in the above quote from the documentation will pull in locale settings from the user's environment. Thus:

```
>>> import locale
>>> # passing an empty string asks for a locale configured on the
>>> # local machine; the return value indicates what that locale is.
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'en_CA.UTF-8'
>>> locale.atof('123,456.789')
123456.789
>>> locale.atof('123456.789')
123456.789
```

The locale will not care if the thousands separators are in the right place - it just recognizes and filters them:

```
>>> locale.atof('12,34,56.789')
123456.789
```

[In 3.6 and up, it will also not care about underscores, which are separately handled by the built-in `float` and `int` conversion](https://peps.python.org/pep-0515/):

```
>>> locale.atof('12_34_56.789')
123456.789
```

On the other side, [the string `format` method, and f-strings, are locale-aware if the `n` format is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823058):

```
>>> f'{123456.789:.9n}' # `.9` specifies 9 significant figures
'123,456.789'
```

Without the previous `setlocale` call, the output would not have the comma.

#### Setting a locale explicitly

It is also possible to make temporary locale settings, using the appropriate locale name, and apply those settings only to a specific aspect of localization. To get localized parsing and formatting only for numbers, for example, use `LC_NUMERIC` rather than `LC_ALL` in the `setlocale` call.

Here are some examples:

```
>>> # in Denmark, periods are thousands separators and commas are decimal points
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_DK.UTF-8')
'en_DK.UTF-8'
>>> locale.atof('123,456.789')
123.456789
>>> # Formatting a number according to the Indian lakh/crore system:
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'en_IN.UTF-8')
'en_IN.UTF-8'
>>> f'{123456.789:9.9n}'
'1,23,456.789'
```

The necessary locale strings [may depend on your operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/955986), and [may require additional work to enable](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=111527).

To get back to how Python behaves by default, use the `C` locale described previously, thus: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')`.

#### Caveats

Setting the locale affects program behaviour globally, and is not thread safe. If done at all, it should normally be done just once at the beginning of the program. Again quoting from documentation:

> It is generally a bad idea to call `setlocale()` in some library routine, since as a side effect it affects the entire program. Saving and restoring it is almost as bad: it is expensive and affects other threads that happen to run before the settings have been restored.

> If, when coding a module for general use, you need a locale independent version of an operation that is affected by the locale (such as certain formats used with `time.strftime()`), you will have to find a way to do it without using the standard library routine. Even better is convincing yourself that using locale settings is okay. Only as a last resort should you document that your module is not compatible with non-`C` locale settings.

When the Python code is embedded within a C program, setting the locale *can even affect the C code*:

> Extension modules should never call `setlocale()`, except to find out what the current locale is. But since the return value can only be used portably to restore it, that is not very useful (except perhaps to find out whether or not the locale is `C`).

(N.B: when `setlocale` is called with a single `category` argument, or with `None` - **not** an empty string - for the locale name, it does not change anything, and simply returns the name of the existing locale.)

So, this is **not** meant as a tool, in production code, to try out experimentally parsing or formatting data that was meant for different locales. The above examples are only examples to illustrate how the system works. For this purpose, seek a third-party internationalization library.

However, if the data is all formatted according to a specific locale, specifying that locale ahead of time will make it possible to use `locale.atoi` and `locale.atof` as drop-in replacements for `int` and `float` calls on string input.

Comment: 11.5 years later, my original version of the answer seems completely unacceptable to me (despite that apparently nobody ever saw fit to downvote it even once) - so I've completely rewritten it. I now thoroughly explain what the `locale` module does, how to figure out a proper locale setting, and the limitations of this approach - giving detailed examples throughout.

Answer (score 12):

If you don't know the locale and you want to parse any kind of number, use [this `parseNumber(text)` function](https://github.com/hayj/SystemTools/blob/master/systemtools/number.py) (My repo). It is not perfect but take into account most cases :

```
>>> parseNumber("a 125,00 €")
125
>>> parseNumber("100.000,000")
100000
>>> parseNumber("100 000,000")
100000
>>> parseNumber("100,000,000")
100000000
>>> parseNumber("100 000 000")
100000000
>>> parseNumber("100.001 001")
100.001
>>> parseNumber("$.3")
0.3
>>> parseNumber(".003")
0.003
>>> parseNumber(".003 55")
0.003
>>> parseNumber("3 005")
3005
>>> parseNumber("1.190,00 €")
1190
>>> parseNumber("1190,00 €")
1190
>>> parseNumber("1,190.00 €")
1190
>>> parseNumber("$1190.00")
1190
>>> parseNumber("$1 190.99")
1190.99
>>> parseNumber("1 000 000.3")
1000000.3
>>> parseNumber("1 0002,1.2")
10002.1
>>> parseNumber("")

>>> parseNumber(None)

>>> parseNumber(1)
1
>>> parseNumber(1.1)
1.1
>>> parseNumber("rrr1,.2o")
1
>>> parseNumber("rrr ,.o")

>>> parseNumber("rrr1rrr")
1
```

Comment: Please include the code as part of your answer. Answers need to be self-contained to prevent link-rot from making the answer useless.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi there are several hundred lines of code. The answer effectively boils down to "use a third-party library", which isn't really answering the question, plus some self-promotion. Aside from that, this implementation is not locale-aware; if we are going to look for third-party libraries, we might as well look for one that is.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree but I feel like I've had previous flags rejected for similar answers so I didn't flag this one. I did downvote it though

Answer (score 11):

If the input uses a comma as a decimal point and period as a thousands separator, use `.replace` twice to convert the data to the format used by the built-in `float`. Thus:

```
s = s.replace('.','').replace(',','.')
number = float(s)
```

Answer (score 5):

What about this?

```
 my_string = "123,456.908"
 commas_removed = my_string.replace(',', '') # remove comma separation
 my_float = float(commas_removed) # turn from string to float.
```

In short:

```
my_float = float(my_string.replace(',', ''))
```

Answer (score 5):

Better solution for [different currency formats](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/9105/international-currency-formatting-guidelines-currency-codes):

```py
def text_currency_to_float(text):
    t = text
    dot_pos = t.rfind('.')
    comma_pos = t.rfind(',')
    if comma_pos > dot_pos:
        t = t.replace(".", "")
        t = t.replace(",", ".")
    else:
        t = t.replace(",", "")
    return float(t)
```

This function detects whether a comma is a thousand separator or a period is a decimal separator, by checking where their positions appear in the string from the right. (The premise is that a thousand separators should not be used in the fractional part of the number.)

Answer (score 2):

```
s =  "123,456.908"
print float(s.replace(',', ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use babel:

```
from babel.numbers import parse_decimal
f = float(parse_decimal("123,456.908", locale="en_US"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way I wrote up for you. :)

```
>>> number = '123,456,789.908'.replace(',', '') # '123456789.908'
>>> float(number)
123456789.908
```

Comment: `re` is a big hammer for such a task.

Comment: @John Doe: Looks way better now. I like `float(number)` because of its descriptive touch. +1 ;-)

Comment: 9 988 776,65 € in France
9.988.776,65 € in Germany
$9,988,776.65 in the United States ----> Are you sure it works?

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest solution, but for the sake of completeness and maybe interesting if you want to rely on an existing function that has been proven a million times: you can leverage [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) by injecting your number as StringIO to its `read_csv()` function (it has a C backend, so the conversion functionality cannot be leveraged directly - as far as I know).

```
>>> float(pd.read_csv(StringIO("1,000.23"), sep=";", thousands=",", header=None)[0])
1000.23
```

Specifically for floats: in case your number uses dots as thousands separator and comma as decimal separator, use the `decimal=","` parameter in addition to setting `thousands="."`.