# Removing " from integer

Tags: python

I have a big function that is importing some lines and most values rows are integers so I can easily make a division like this:

```py
price_unit_calc = float(inv_row[7]) / float(inv_row[6])
```

but I get an error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1,000.000
```

this is because `inv_row[7]` sometimes is a "1,000.000" and not 1.000.00

Question is how can I remove those " if they appear in a row?

UPDATE:
if I do

```
 price_unit_calc = float(inv_row[7].replace(',','.')) / float(inv_row[6].replace(',','.'))
```

i still get

```
File "/home//workspace/odoo-9.0/addons/config/wizard/import_wizard.py", line 39, in do_import
    price_unit_calc = float(inv_row[7].replace(',','.')) / float(inv_row[6].replace(',','.'))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1.000.000
```

UPDATE2:

```
price_unit_calc = float(inv_row[7].replace(',','')) / float(inv_row[6].replace(',',''))
```

and error

```
File "/home/antonp/workspace/odoo-9.0/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 362, in _symbol_set_float
    result = __builtin__.float(x or 0.0)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1,000.000
```

Comment: No. the `,` is the error here. So, remove it before converting to float. `inv_row[7].replace(",", "")`

Comment: remove the comma with `str.replace` and it should work

Comment: `1.000.000` is also an invalid literal.  If you really want to have a separator for the various places, you can use underscores: `1_000.000` is the same as `1000.0`

Comment: You've replaced `','` with `'.'`. That's still invalid. You should have replaced `','` with an empty string `''`.

Comment: Now you're getting a similar error in a different place in your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - convert string to float (the conventional method, float(), is not working in this case)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16201286/python-convert-string-to-float-the-conventional-method-float-is-not-worki)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment section the `,` is the problem. So, you need to remove it since it is only relevant for formatting (it doesn't change the actual value)

```
inv_row[7].replace(",", "")
```

Also, if your `inv_row` is a list containing only floats values like `1,000.000`, what you should do instead is iterate over the list and apply the above logic instead of finding everywhere in your code where it *could possibly* result in an error,

```
for index,item in enumerate(inv_row):
     inv_row[index] = item.replace(",", "")
```

---

Now, for what you tried,

```
 inv_row[7].replace(",", ".")
```

This will result in adding multiple `.` to your string representation will which will also lead to the error.

Comment: well now its File "/home/antonp/workspace/odoo-9.0/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 362, in _symbol_set_float
    result = __builtin__.float(x or 0.0)
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1,000.000

Comment: @Chaban33 That's the same problem. You need to remove the comma from your string.

Comment: @Chaban33 No, that's the error at another place in your code where you have the same problem.

Comment: `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 1,000.000` there is clearly still a comma in one of your value.

Answer (score 2):

You have to remove the commas in the numbers by replacing them with empty strings:

```
price_unit_calc = float(inv_row[7].replace(',','')) / float(inv_row[6].replace(',',''))
```