# pandas.read_html not support decimal comma

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, xlm

I was reading an xlm file using `pandas.read_html` and works almost perfect, the problem is that the file has commas as decimal separators instead of dots (the default in `read_html`).

I could easily replace the commas by dots in one file, but i have almost 200 files with that configuration. 
with `pandas.read_csv` you can define the decimal separator, but i don't know why in `pandas.read_html` you can only define the thousand separator.

any guidance in this matter?, there is another way to automate the comma/dot replacement before it is open by pandas? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: So your 1000.21 in your file is 1000,21?

Comment: @zhqiat actually its `1.000,21`, it also has the thousand separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @zhqiat. I think upgrading `pandas` to version `0.19` will solve the problem. unfortunately I couldn't found an easy way to accomplish that. I found a tutorial to upgrade Pandas but for [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70883/how-do-i-install-python-pandas/70885) (winXP user).

I finally chose the workaround, using the method posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17550789/5318634), basically converting all columns, one by one, to a numeric type of `pandas.Series`

```
result[col] = result[col].apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(".","").str.replace(",","."))
```

I know that this solution ain't the best, but works. Thanks

Answer (score 27):

This did not start working for me until I used both  decimal=',' and thousands='.'

Pandas version: 0.23.4

So try to use both decimal and thousands:
i.e.:
`pd.read_html(io="http://example.com", decimal=',', thousands='.')`

Before I would only use decimal=',' and the number columns would be saved as type str with the numbers just omitting the comma.(weird behaviour) For example 0,7 would be "07" and "1,9" would be "19"

It is still being saved in the dataframe as type str but at least I don't have to manually put in the dots. The numbers are correctly displayed; 0,7 -> "0.7"

Comment: This helped me for pandas version 1.1.2 too: when I added `thousands='.'` the decimal parameter worked

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the source code of [read_html](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/io/html.py)

```
def read_html(io, match='.+', flavor=None, header=None, index_col=None,
              skiprows=None, attrs=None, parse_dates=False,
              tupleize_cols=False, thousands=',', encoding=None,
              decimal='.', converters=None, na_values=None,
              keep_default_na=True):
```

The function header implies that there is a decimal separator available in the function call.

Further down in the documentation this looks like it was added in version 0.19 (so a bit further down the experimental branch). Can you upgrade your pandas?

> decimal : str, default '.'
>           Character to recognize as decimal point (e.g. use ',' for European
>           data).
>           .. versionadded:: 0.19.0

Comment: right now Im using the last stable version (default in anaconda). i will try to upgrade to 0.19 and see if that works.
    pd.__version__ 
    u'0.18.1'

as soon as I try, I will be back

Answer (score 1):

I am using pandas 0.19 but it still fails to correctly convert the numbers.

For example:

```
a=pd.read_html(r.text,thousands='.',decimal=',')
```

will recognize the value "1.401,40" in a table cell as 140140 (float).

I use a similar solution as 'Pablo A', just correcting for nan values:

```
def to_numeric_comma(series):
    new=series.apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('.','').replace(',','.'))
    new=pd.to_numeric(new.replace('nan',pd.np.nan))
    return new
```