# Make Python think of comma as dot, only on one sentence?

Tags: python, floating-point

I have this piece of code:

```
grams = float(order_weight[2].rstrip("g"))
```

Which is inside a bsoup function that looks for the grams on one page. The format of the grams is: X,XXX.XX. By that I mean, uses comma for the thousands, and dots for the decimals.

I keep getting errors:

```
invalid literal for float(): 1,759.33
```

The number is a example. Is that becuase the comma should be where the dot is and other way around? Can I change it only on this sentence?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your problem is that there are commas at all, not that they are in the wrong place! The solution by @thefourtheye fixes that.

Comment: Oh, so there shouldn't be any commas for numbers in the thousands? Thanks for the clarification to the answer @kqr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply replace the commas with empty string

```
float(order_weight[2].rstrip("g").replace(',',''))
```

This was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633912/1903116. The actual way to deal with this, is to use proper locale

```
from locale import *
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, '')
print atof('1,759.33')
```

**Output**

```
1759.33
```

Answer (score 2):

```
float(order_weight[2].rstrip("g").replace(",", ""))
```