# mean of items in a weird list

Tags: python

I have a list in python and I want to get the average of all items. I tried different functions and even I wrote a small function for that but could not do that. even when I tried to convert the items to a int or float it gave these errors:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

here is a small example of my list in python.

```
['0,0459016', '0,0426647', '0,0324087', '0,0222222', '0,0263356']
```

do you guys know how to get the average of items in such list/
thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that '0,0459016' means '0.0459016':

```
In [6]: l = ['0,0459016', '0,0426647', '0,0324087', '0,0222222', '0,0263356']

In [7]: reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda z: float(z.replace(',', '.')), l)) / len(l)
Out[7]: 0.033906559999999995
```

Comment: why not use `sum` instead of reimplementing it using `reduce`?

Comment: Yes, `sum` could be used too. Didn't strike me while writing the post.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [How can I convert a string with dot and comma into a float number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-number-in-python)

```
sum([float(v.replace(",", ".")) for v in a]) / len(a)
```

where `a` is your original list.

Comment: If a question can be answered by an existing post, please mark the question as a duplicate instead of making an identical answer. Additionally, this is the wrong method - you really should be using the `locale` module.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
In [1]: sum(map(float,[i.replace(',','.') for i in lst]))/len(lst)
Out[1]: 0.033906559999999995
```

Actulluy there is 2 problem in your list. The elements are string and instead of `.` it having `,`. So we have to convert to normal form. like this.

```
In [11]: map(float,[i.replace(',','.') for i in lst])
Out[11]: [0.0459016, 0.0426647, 0.0324087, 0.0222222, 0.0263356]
```

Then perform the average.