# sort function in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. i sorted a list of string values but
'8,13' '8,14'.... and '9,11' '9,12'.... values came to last. what causes this error?
I typed this in terminal.

```
a = ['13,7', '14,7', '15,7', '12,8', '13,8', '14,8', '15,8', '16,8', 
     '11,9', '12,9', '13,9', '16,9', '10,10', '11,10', '12,10', 
     '16,10', '9,11', '10,11', '11,11', '16,11', '9,12', '10,12', 
     '16,12', '8,13', '9,13', '10,13', '15,13', '16,13', '8,14', 
     '9,14', '15,14', '16,14', '17,14', '8,15', '9,15', '14,15', 
     '16,15', '17,15', '18,15', '19,15', '8,16', '9,16', '12,16', 
     '13,16', '17,16', '18,16', '19,16', '8,17', '9,17', '10,17', 
     '11,17', '12,17', '9,18', '10,18', '11,18']

a.sort()

a
#['10,10', '10,11', '10,12', '10,13', '10,17', '10,18', '11,10', 
# '11,11', '11,17', '11,18', '11,9', '12,10', '12,16', '12,17', 
# '12,8', '12,9', '13,16', '13,7', '13,8', '13,9', '14,15', '14,7', 
# '14,8', '15,13', '15,14', '15,7', '15,8', '16,10', '16,11', '16,12', 
# '16,13', '16,14', '16,15', '16,8', '16,9', '17,14', '17,15', 
# '17,16', '18,15', '18,16', '19,15', '19,16', '8,13', '8,14', '8,15', 
# '8,16', '8,17', '9,11', '9,12', '9,13', '9,14', '9,15', '9,16', 
# '9,17', '9,18']
```

Comment: Sorting `str` is not same as sorting `int` `tuple`

Comment: you are sorting strings, not numbers, so alphabetical logic is applied

Comment: Convert your list into a list of numbers with `[float(x) for x in a]`, then sort.

Comment: it shows an error '[float(x) for x in a]'

Comment: Is "13,7" supposed to be *one* number or *two* numbers?

Comment: Is the comma supposed to be a decimal point, or do you have a string of two integers?  If two integers, then which do you wish to sort on, the leftmost or the rightmost?

Comment: it's a string of two int and to sort based on leftmost value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. The commas require an additional step.

```
a = [float(i.replace(',', '.')) for i in a]
a.sort()
```

Reference this post: [How can I convert a string with dot and comma into a float number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-number-in-python) for the actual Pythonic way to handle numbers that use commas instead of decimal points.

Comment: @rajiniraja Doesn't this destroy your data? You said the values represent two ints, and after this you don't have them anymore.

Comment: Indeed it destroy my data, but I get the idea. I split the string by comma as separator and convert it into int and append it to list. Finally sort function results my desired output. Thanks for the efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Your list elements are of type `str`, so you need to either convert them to `int` tuple before sorting or you may use `lambda` as `key` argument to `sort` method for on the fly conversion as:

```
>>> a.sort(key=lambda x:map(int, x.split(",")))
>>> ['8,13', '8,14', '8,15', '8,16', '8,17', '9,11', '9,12', '9,13', '9,14', '9,15', '9,16', '9,17', '9,18', '10,10', '10,11', '10,12', '10,13', '10,17', '10,18', '11,9', '11,10', '11,11', '11,17', '11,18', '12,8', '12,9', '12,10', '12,16', '12,17', '13,7', '13,8', '13,9', '13,16', '14,7', '14,8', '14,15', '15,7', '15,8', '15,13', '15,14', '16,8', '16,9', '16,10', '16,11', '16,12', '16,13', '16,14', '16,15', '17,14', '17,15', '17,16', '18,15', '18,16', '19,15', '19,16']
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is natural sort. Use natsort a third party library and sort.

```
>>> import natsort
>>> natsort.natsorted(a)
['8,13', '8,14', '8,15', '8,16', '8,17', '9,11', '9,12', '9,13', '9,14', '9,15', '9,16', '9,17', '9,18', '10,10', '10,11', '10,12', '10,13', '10,17', '10,18', '11,9', '11,10', '11,11', '11,17', '11,18', '12,8', '12,9', '12,10', '12,16', '12,17', '13,7', '13,8', '13,9', '13,16', '14,7', '14,8', '14,15', '15,7', '15,8', '15,13', '15,14', '16,8', '16,9', '16,10', '16,11', '16,12', '16,13', '16,14', '16,15', '17,14', '17,15', '17,16', '18,15', '18,16', '19,15', '19,16']
```

Sorting is between strings. It compares letter by letter of the string. eg when comparing string '10,10' and '9,18' its first compares '1' and '9' then '0' and ',' so on. That's the reason you are not getting the desired result.