# how to convert number < 1 from string to float python

Tags: python

my question is simple.

I got my string :

```
a = '0,0127'
```

I want to convert it to a number but when i compile

```
float(a)
```

i got the following message error :

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0,0127'

Is there another way to convert it to a number ?

Comment: `print(float(a.replace(",", ".")))`

Comment: Ah the problem is the coma ? perfect

Comment: Take a look at [the documentation of `float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) which describes the syntax that can be parsed.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-in-python

Comment: Thanks didn't pay any attention that i get a coma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.replace`

**Ex:**

```
a = '0,0127'
print(float(a.replace(",", ".")))
```

**Output:**

```
0.0127
```

Comment: Beat me by 21 seconds. =)

Answer (score 3):

The reason this isn't working is because the decimal type only recognizes periods (`.`) for the decimal delimiter as this is what is common in, e.g., english. You could manually change the string or do

```
a = a.replace(",", ".")
float(a)
```

Which should work.