# How to format a float with a comma as decimal separator in an f-string?

Tags: python, floating-point, format, f-string

For some machine control in python, I write the results to a text-file, that someone else can copy into Excel (this is the most convenient way in this situation). However, in the Netherlands, Excel has a comma as decimal separator and thus I want to have the result "position" in the text-file as 123,456, but when I use the f-string method like this:

```
    resultfile.write(f"Position\t{position:.5}")
```

This will obviously result in a dot decimal separator.

How can I change this to a comma without iterating through the whole file int the end and replace the dots with commas?

Comment: An fstring is just a string, so `f"Position\t{position:.5}".replace('.', ',')` should work just fine, right?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6633912/962190 This answer talks about a different issue (printing number with comma separation every three decimal positions), but the locale setting might influence your format as well.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to format floats with a comma *within* the f-string, you can either use replace after casting the float to a string:

```py
position = 123.456
f"Position\t{str(position).replace('.',',')}"
```

A second option is to use the Python standard library module locale ([but it is not thread-safe](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html)):

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'nl_NL')
f"Position\t{locale.format('%.3f', position)}"
```

A third option is to use the library [babel](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/) (preferred in case of library routines):

```py
from babel.numbers import format_decimal
f"Position\t{format_decimal(position, locale='nl_NL')}"
```

All three options return the same result for the given example:

```
'Position\t123,456'
```

Answer (score 3):

As @michel-de-ruiter [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65339202/1303378), the `f` format does not work with locale. On the other hand, you can't set the precision using `n` format. For example, if you want 4 digits after decimal separator:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'nl_NL')

position = 123.45678999
print(f'{position:.4n}')  # output: 123,4 (not quite what we wanted!)
```

However, you can round the number with the desired precision before formatting it:

```py
print(f'{round(position, 4):n}')  # output: 123,4567 (that's it!)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you prefer to avoid dependencies, the following simple function might fit your needs:

```
def comma_num(n,f=''):
    return ('{'+f+'}').format(n).replace('.',',')

n = 1.23

f'Whatever {comma_num(n)}'
'Whatever {}'.format(comma_num(n))
>>>'Whatever 1,23'

f'Whatever {comma_num(n,":6.4f")}'
'Whatever {}'.format(comma_num(n,':6.4f'))
>>>'Whatever 1,2300'
```

Answer (score 2):

If the `g` format is good enough for you, use [`n`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) instead:

```
resultfile.write(f"Position\t{position:.7n}")
```

While `n` works (uses the current locale setting when used) instead of both `d` *and* `g`, there is no such thing for the `f` format unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'pt_PT')

def fmt(a, dec=2):
    x = int(a)
    return f".{len(str(x))+dec}n"

def main():
    # usage example
    a = 110.12345
    print(f'{a:{fmt(a)}}')
    print(f'{a:{fmt(a,3)}}')

    # here it is
    print(f"{fmt(a) = }")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

gets you this:

```
110,12
110,123
fmt(a) = '.5n'

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score -3):

A simpler solution might be:

```py
f"Position\t{position:,.5f}"
```

Comment: This changes the _thousands separator_ to `,` but the question is asking about the _decimal separator_. It doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @seaver This does *not* answer the question. All this does is introducing a thousands separator (`,`). It does *not* change the decimal separator (stays `.`).