# How to make that f"..." string formatting uses comma instead of dot as decimal separator?

Tags: python, windows, floating-point, decimal, locale

I tried:

```
import locale
print(locale.locale_alias)
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "french")
print(f"{3.14:.2f}")
```

but the output is `3.14` whereas I would like `3,14`.

**How to do this with f"..." string formatting?**

Note: I don't want to use `.replace(".", ",")`

Note: I'm looking for a Windows solution, and solutions from [How to format a float with a comma as decimal separator in an f-string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379722/how-to-format-a-float-with-a-comma-as-decimal-separator-in-an-f-string) don't work (thus it's not a duplicate on Windows):

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'nl_NL')
# or
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR')
```

> locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: @matszwecja No, I'm on Windows, and these methods don't work out-of-the-box.

Comment: I've just tested and all 3 methods in accepted answer work just fine on Windows for me

Comment: If I use your code and change `print(f"{3.14:.2f}")` to `print(f"{3.14:.3n}")` I get `3,14` as described in one of the answers.

Comment: @user56700 You're right. I think you can post it as an answer.

Comment: @matszwecja In my case with `.3f` it does not work, but with `.3n` it does

Comment: @Basj The solution is from linked question, so it's still a clear duplicate for me. Regardless, keep in mind that `n` option only uses current locale. The code is not guaranteed to print it with comma if your current locale does not support that.

Comment: @matszwecja The strange thing is that `.2f` prints 2 digits after `.`, but with `.2n` we *only* have 1 digit after `,`. Why? Thus `.3n` is needed here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I looked up the answers on the duplicate flagged page and found an answer that worked:

Change `print(f"{3.14:.2f}")` to `print(f"{3.14:.3n}")` and you will get the result: `3,14`

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language:

> `'n'` Number. This is the same as 'g', except that it uses the current locale setting to insert the appropriate number separator characters.

Whereas `'g'` is described at:

> `g` General format. For a given precision p >= 1, this rounds the number to p significant digits and then formats the result in either fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its magnitude. A precision of 0 is treated as equivalent to a precision of 1.
> ...Truncated...

The `'f'` description is:

> `'f'` Fixed-point notation. For a given precision p, formats the number as a decimal number with exactly p digits following the decimal point.

Comment: The strange thing is that `.2f` prints 2 digits after `.`, but with `.2n` we *only* have 1 digit after `,`. Why?

Comment: @Basj You copied the integer notation description, where it should've been the float description. I've updated the answer. Btw thanks for adding the link etc. `n` is rounding the last digit, that's why you need 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "locale.format_string" instead of "f string"

Try this instead :

```
import locale
# Set the locale to "french"
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')
# Format the number 3.14 with 2 decimal places, using the french locale
print(locale.format_string("%.2f", 3.14, grouping=True))
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of time has elapsed after the question, but I will add an answer for future reference.

As the other answers have indicated, `n` will automatically pick up your locale settings (which is one of its purposes), but the precision number works differently to what you anticipate. 3.14:.2n indicated that you want 2 digits. This isn't referring to the number of decimal places in the number, but to the overall number. So decimal places will be rounded down if necessary.

`f` is used to control decimal precision, but does not support locale formatting. To use the `f` notation in a locale sensitive way, it is necessary to format the number using `locale.format_string()` function:

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, "fr_FR.UTF-8")
print(f"{3.14:.3n}")
# 3,14
print(f"{3.14:.2n}")
# 3,1
print(f"{3.14:.1n}")
# 3
print(locale.format_string("%.2f", 3.14))
# 3,14
```

If you want to use `n` formatter, and still require decimal precision, then the [round()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/round.html) function is an option.

```py
print(f'{round(3.14, 2):n}')
# 3,14
```