# How do I make python detect the commas?

Tags: python

Updated code:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import webbrowser
from termcolor import colored
import locale

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, '')

print(colored('Lowest Priced Limited\n---------------------\n', 'green'))
count = 0
while True:
    lowestprice = 1234567890
    for limited in requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?CatalogContext=1&Keyword=&SortType=0&SortAggregation=3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Category=2&pageNumber=1').json():
        price = locale.atof(limited['BestPrice'])
        if price < lowestprice:
            limitedname = limited['Name']
            limitedurl = limited['AbsoluteUrl']
            lowestprice = price
    print(colored(f"{limitedname}: {lowestprice}\n{limitedurl}\n"))
    sleep(1)

    if lowestprice <= 220 and count == 0:
        webbrowser.open(limitedurl, new=2)
        count += 1
```

Comment: You can use the method ```replace(",",".")``` and ```float```

Comment: Its better to use it as a currency or you may get into problems by replacing commas or points
https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/320929/currency-formatting-in-python

Comment: @AlexDotis I think it's supposed to be 3799 not 3.799, so even though it's a hacky and incorrect way of doing things, it should be int not float

Comment: When I used float instead of int, I got the error ```price = float(limited['BestPrice'])
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3,799' ```

Comment: @DerekEden take a look here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633523/how-can-i-convert-a-string-with-dot-and-comma-into-a-float-in-python This may answer this question.

Comment: If you are going to convert the string to int  or float you have to replace the , with '' as stated above. Though the locale method is the proper way to do it

Comment: you can use `lowestprice = sys.maxint` as your initial value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the locale module to convert price notation into a float value.

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.atof("1,000.99")
1000.99
```

Or if you want integer values only:

```
>>> locale.atoi("1,000")
1000
```

Depending on your configuration, you may need:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,'')
```

May also work:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8')
```

As suggested by others, you can just remove the commas and convert to a float:

```
price = float(limited['BestPrice'].replace(',', ''))
```

However, it's better to get familiar with localization resources for a more professional solution.

To skip invalid numeric strings like an empty string:

```
for limited in requests.get('...').json():
    try:
        price = locale.atof(limited['BestPrice'])
        # or
        # price = float(limited['BestPrice'].replace(',', ''))
        if price < lowestprice:
            limitedname = limited['Name']
            limitedurl = limited['AbsoluteUrl']
            lowestprice = price

    except ValueError as ve:
        print(f"Hit a non-numeric value for {limited['Name']} for price: {ve}")

print(colored(f"{limitedname}: {lowestprice}\n{limitedurl}\n"))
sleep(1)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211038/discussion-on-answer-by-todd-how-do-i-make-python-detect-the-commas).

Answer (score 0):

Added this sample code in the hopes that it helps you understand what's going on, though @Todd has definitely covered what you need to do from multiple different angles.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC,'')
import requests
for limited in requests.get('https://search.roblox.com/catalog/json?Catalog'\
                            'Context=1&Keyword=&SortType=0&SortAggregation='\
                                '3&SortCurrency=0&LegendExpanded=true&Categ'\
                                    'ory=2&pageNumber=1').json():
    if limited['BestPrice'] == '':
        print('This one is empty')
    else:
        print(locale.atof(limited['BestPrice']))
```

result:

```
4195.0
6997.0
2200.0
8149.0
4291.0
2850.0
3299.0
1998.0
23000.0
3000.0
14500.0
10994.0
3996.0
1249.0
3799.0
6499.0
843.0
3100.0
1300.0
680.0
2049.0
2491.0
4099.0
2499.0
2959.0
10500.0
855.0
8698.0
2700.0
3500.0
19500.0
5199.0
8999.0
55555.0
2844.0
2299.0
5000.0
1399.0
699420.0
This one is empty
55000.0
4400.0
```

These are the bestprice values that are occurring in `limited` as you iterate over the json. These are the values you need to work with. One of them is an empty string.